# How can I Remove .DS_Store files from a Git repository?

Tags: macos, git, gitignore

How can I remove those annoying Mac OS X `.DS_Store` files from a Git repository?

Comment: See: http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/

Comment: Think this is the same in many versions of MacOS, not only Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3408, accepted):

Remove existing `.DS_Store` files from the repository:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
```

Add this line:

```
.DS_Store
```

to the file `.gitignore`, which can be found at the top level of your repository (or create the file if it isn't there already). You can do this easily with this command in the top directory:

```
echo .DS_Store >> .gitignore
```

Then commit the file to the repo:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m '.DS_Store banished!'
```

Comment: You could also use the exec option to find
find . -name .DS_Store -exec git-rm {} \;

It would be one less command.

Comment: It's really trivial, but using `-exec` will launch `git-rm` once for every .DS_Store file, while `xargs` will put all the paths on one command line.  Mostly I prefer `xargs` because I don't have to worry about escaping a lot of special characters.

Comment: This should use .git/info/exclude, not .gitignore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally/1753078#1753078 for an explanation of the difference between the two.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't agree. It would never be useful for a .DS_Store file to be checked in, so it makes more sense as a repository-wide, all-users setting, rather than something each Mac user needs to remember to set on her own machine.

Comment: Works great, just need to change "git-rm" to "git rm" to work with newer versions of git.

Comment: Does adding `.DS_Store` to `.gitignore` work recursively? That is, will it ignore `some/level/of/folders/.DS_Store` as well?

Comment: @CharlieS Yes, if the pattern does not contain a slash, it is matched against the file name in all directories.

Comment: Does the answer still applies on ubuntu? I am getting this usage error usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

Comment: What about: `find . -name .DS_Store -delete`?

Comment: @kenorb That will remove the files but won't notify git of the change, so you would still need to follow that up with `git add` or something like it.

Comment: You can also `find . -name .DS_Store -exec git rm -f --ignore-unmatch '{}' +` -- this works like `xargs` but is shorter to type.

Comment: It's a shame that in 2016, the .gitignore for Swift at Gihub does not include DS_Store from the beginning... or does it?

Comment: @NicolasMiari [it does](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4af9d0a1e3d434bccf9544976c54b22db83c2c18/.gitignore#L35), however I recommend to [ignore such files globally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/108108/2123108)

Comment: That is Apple's .gitignore, isn't it? I just created a repo and chose the Swift .gitignore, but .DS_Store **was missing** (had to add it and go throught all the cleanup mentioned in this answer). Github's official version (if my Google search led me to the right place) of the file seems to still be missing it: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore

Comment: @NicolasMiari There's no point in discussing GitHub's gitignore project here, comment on the relevant pull request: https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2109

Comment: @benzado Using -exec with + will only execute git rm one time: `find . -name .DS_Store -exec git rm -f {} +` https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: Noob question here: What is this type of command `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch` called and how can I learn these?

Comment: @user122121 I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "type" of command; you should open a new question and/or read the Bash manual.

Comment: Downvote because this does not solve the underlying underlying [sic] problem. The other answer does.

Comment: @benzado I think it's weird for the repo to ignore contributor-specific temp files. What if Ubuntu started creating its own, we ignore them too? Same with Vim swapfiles, Emacs, etc. But... eh, I don't really care, I just use .gitignore for this cause it's easier, and everyone uses a Mac anyway.

Comment: @RajarshiGanguly that is find command and OP is piping the result to remove all >ds_store association. It is bash scripting

Comment: @AndrewGrimm That's a pretty Grim way of looking at it. Actually it depends on the repo itself: policy, who's the ones committing/working on it, the purpose of the repo - and as was pointed out there is no reason to have .DS_Store in revision control anyway is there so why not have it as in .gitignore? One is not 'better' or more 'correct' than the other whatever one might say to the contrary. I use .gitignore and I have my reasons and since they're my repos it's my rules and not the rules of someone or some people on SO who say otherwise.

Comment: I get this issue: `find: -: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: git status | grep DS_Store | awk '{print $1}' >> .gitignore

Comment: @MohammadSelimMiah That will ignore any existing `.DS_Store` files, and _only_ those files. Any new ones created in other directories won't be ignored. Also, you'll have multiple lines in your `.gitignore` when only one is needed.

Comment: @benzado I don't think it belongs to a repository wide configuration file, as Mac users are expected to adapt to the rest of us (not the opposite).

Comment: @6infinity8 What belongs or doesn't belong in `.gitignore` is up to the human beings who share the repository. No one else's opinions matter. The whole purpose of Git is to enable a group of humans to collaborate and build something together. Git is wonderful because it can adapt to the needs of different groups of humans.

Comment: @benzado `find . -name .DS_Store -exec git rm -f --ignore-unmatch {} +` is the same as `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch`. In the `find` page of the man page manual:
-exec utility [argument ...] {} +
      Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many path-
      names as possible for each invocation of utility. This behaviour
      is similar to that of xargs(1).

Comment: Note for noobies like me: when I ran the command on the windows terminal, returned me an error message ```xargs : The term 'xargs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...```. I had to open a git bash terminal and ran the command. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 287):

Combining benzado and webmat's answers, updating with `git rm`, not failing on files found that aren't in repo, and making it paste-able generically for any user:

```bash
# remove any existing files from the repo, skipping over ones not in repo
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
# specify a global exclusion list
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
# adding .DS_Store to that list
echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore
```

Comment: I found that when using a git repo in my home directory (AKA a "dotfiles" repo), having `~/.gitignore` as my global excludes file is a pain. There are files that I want to exclude from my home directory that I _don't_ want to ignore globally. I use `~/.gitexcludes` instead via the same directive: `core.excludesfile`

Answer (score 218):

The best solution to tackle this issue is to Globally ignore these files from all the git repos on your system. This can be done by creating a global gitignore file like:

```
vi ~/.gitignore_global
```

Adding Rules for ignoring files like:

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Now, add this file to your global git config:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Edit:

Removed Icons as they might need to be committed as application assets.

Comment: You can also add above rules in your repository's .gitignore. This would keep away these files at repo level if there are multiple contributors to your project. However, in such cases, .gitignore should deal with every OS' specific files etc if different developers are using different OS. Like rules for linux, OSX etc.

Comment: I would recommend that each developer deals with his os specific files in his own .global_ignore, that way the project .gitignore is project specific.

Comment: must run: git add .gitignore_global ,  in order another programmers have that file too in his local environment ?

Comment: @stackdave No. That file isn't even under git control. That's in the home directory and they would have to update their git config too. There isn't even a reason to do it this way. No need to make a new file when there already exists the files for the same purpose. Each directory can have a .gitignore and there's also the repo specific info/exclude. Also - though I'm vague on this one - I think you can use ~/.gitignore too (not certain!). Oh and I have repos that have .jar files and .log files too so that could be a problem for some (and I imagine other people different extensions added here).

Comment: As I am new to get I find this to be a fantastic resource for me at first glance, but I was wondering if there is a video or article someone could point me to so I can understand the reasons behind why the file types are typically ignored. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mcfedr Yes, that would be wonderful! However, some novice developers might not do so and could accidentally check in some common OS-specific garbage. Preemptively adding likely threats to the project's "hygiene" to its .gitignore seems reasonable to me in some cases.

Answer (score 66):

In some situations you may also want to ignore some files globally. For me, .DS_Store is one of them. Here's how:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile /Users/mat/.gitignore
```

(Or any file of your choice)

Then edit the file just like a repo's .gitignore. Note that I think you have to use an absolute path.

Answer (score 55):

Sometimes .DS_Store files are there at remote repository, but not visible at your local project folders. To fix this, we need to remove all cached files and add again.

**Step 1:** Add this to .gitignore file.

```
# Ignore Mac DS_Store files
.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
```

**Step 2:** Remove the cached files and add again using these commands.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -am "Removed git ignored files"
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: `**/.DS_Store` line is not needed actually, adding `.DS_Store` is enough.

Comment: No it isn't enough. Because it keeps in sub directories.

Answer (score 53):

If you are unable to remove the files because they have changes staged use:

```
git rm --cached -f *.DS_Store
```

Comment: For me this worked out: `git rm --cached -f .DS_Store`

Answer (score 47):

The best way to get rid of this file forever:

Make a global `.gitignore` file:

```bash
echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore_global
```

Let Git know that you want to use this file for all of your repositories:

```bash
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

That’s it! `.DS_Store` will be ignored in all repositories.

Comment: This is great as it affects all repos and I didn't even had to change the repo .gitignore (saving a PR)

Answer (score 30):

Top voted answer is awesome, but helping out the rookies like me, here is how to create the .gitignore file, edit it, save it, remove the files you might have already added to git, then push up the file to Github.

**Create the .gitignore file**

To create a .gitignore file, you can just `touch` the file which creates a blank file with the specified name. We want to create the file named .gitignore so we can use the command:

`touch .gitignore`

**Ignore the files**

Now you have to add the line which tells git to ignore the DS Store files to your .gitignore. You can use the nano editor to do this.

`nano .gitignore`

Nano is nice because it includes instructions on how to get out of it. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to exit)

Copy and paste some of the ideas from this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657) which lists some common files to ignore. The most important ones, to answer this question, would be:

```
# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
```

The # are comments, and will help you organize your file as it grows.

This [Github article](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) also has some general ideas and guidelines.

**Remove the files already added to git**

Finally, you need to actually remove those DS Store files from your directory.

Use this great command from the top voted answer. This will go through all the folders in your directory, and remove those files from git.

`find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch`

**Push .gitignore up to Github**

Last step, you need to actually commit your .gitignore file.

`git status`

`git add .gitignore`

`git commit -m '.DS_Store banished!'`

Comment: the touch command in your steps isn't necessary... nano will create the file for you.

Comment: I found my own answer 2 years later and used it. Good work past me. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Open terminal and type "cd < ProjectPath >"

1. Remove existing files:
   `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch`
2. `nano .gitignore`
3. Add this `.DS_Store`
4. type "ctrl + x"
5. Type "y"
6. Enter to save file
7. `git add .gitignore`
8. `git commit -m '.DS_Store removed.'`

Comment: `nano .gitignore` creates the file if not present, this command should be executed from project root folder

Comment: @Saif Not necessarily. You can have .gitignore in any directory where you want to exclude some files in a subdirectory but not the root directory. I have this in a number of my repos for example.

Answer (score 19):

I had to change git-rm to git rm in the above to get it to work:

```
find . -depth -name '.DS_Store' -exec git rm --cached '{}' \; -print
```

Answer (score 19):

Use this command to remove the existing files:

```
find . -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

Then add `.DS_Store` to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 14):

If .DS_Store was never added to your git repository, simply add it to your .gitignore file.

**If you don't have one, create a file called**

```
.gitignore
```

In your the root directory of your app and simply write

```
.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
**/._.DS_Store
```

In it. This will never allow the .DS_Store file to sneak in your git.

**if it's already there, write in your terminal:**

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
```

then commit and push the changes to remove the .DS_Store from your remote repo:

```
git commit -m "Remove .DS_Store from everywhere"
git push origin master
```

And now add .DS_Store to your .gitignore file, and then again commit and push with the 2 last pieces of code (git commit..., git push...)

**Other Solution**

If .DS_Store already committed:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

To ignore them in all repository: (sometimes it named ._.DS_Store)

```
echo ".DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Answer (score 13):

In case you want to remove DS_Store files to every folder and subfolder:

---

In case of already committed DS_Store:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

Ignore them by:

```
echo ".DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Answer (score 12):

#### Step 1

This will remove every `.DS_Store` file in a directory (including subdirectories)

```sh
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
```

#### Step 2

Add this to `.gitignore` to prevent any DS_Store files in the **root directory *and* every subdirectory** from going to git!

```
**/.DS_Store
```

From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> - A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

Comment: Working perfectly!

Answer (score 10):

delete them using `git-rm`, and then add .DS_Store to `.gitignore` to stop them getting added again. You can also use [blueharvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/) to stop them getting created all together

Answer (score 9):

The following worked best for me.  Handled unmatched files, and files with local modifications.  For reference, this was on a Mac 10.7 system running git 1.7.4.4.

Find and remove:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch -f
```

I also globally ignore .DS_Store across all repositories by setting a global core.excludesfile.

First, create the file (if one doesn't already exist):

```
touch ~/.gitignore
```

Then add the following line and save:

```
.DS_Store
```

Now configure git to respect the file globally:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 7):

I found that the following line from [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/5206/removing-dsstore-files-from-a-git-checkout/) does best on wiping all `.DS_Store`, including one that has local modifications.

```
find . -depth -name '.DS_Store' -exec git-rm --cached '{}' \; -print
```

`--cached` option, keeps your local `.DS_Store` since it gonna be reproduced anyway.

And just like mentioned all above, add `.DS_Store` to .gitignore file on the root of your project. Then it will be no longer in your sight (of repos).

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I have a good answer.
To remove the .DS_Store files, use the following commands from a terminal window, but be very careful deleting files with 'find'. Using a specific name with the -name option is one of the safer ways to use it:

```
cd directory/above/affected/workareas
find . -name .DS_Store -delete
```

You can leave off the "-delete" if you want to simply list them before and after. That will reassure you that they're gone.

With regard to the ~/.gitignore_global advice: be careful here.
You want to place that nice file into .gitignore within the
top level of each workarea and commit it, so that anyone who clones your repo will gain the benefit of its use.

Comment: Indeed: whenever you are going to do a destructive command it is arguably best to start out by printing the files that will be affected before actually doing the destructive command. It can save you a great deal of pain (esp if you're one who doesn't backup though even those of us who regularly backup can be saved time this way)!

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
find . -name "*.DS_Store" -type f -exec git-rm {} \;
```

It deletes all files whose names end with `.DS_Store`, including `._.DS_Store`.

Comment: The asterisk should not be in there.

Comment: asterisk should be there because i found .DS_Store and ._.DS_Store files on my mac system.

Comment: @MutantMahesh. In that case, you need `"*.DS_Store"`, so that the asterisk is passed to `find` rather than expanded by the shell.

Comment: `git-rm` not found

Answer (score 6):

For some reason none of the above worked on my mac.

My solution is from the terminal run:

```
rm .DS_Store
```

Then run following command:

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: that's because you are trying to remove it from the local. whereas the question asks about to remove it from git.

Comment: One day I upvoted the answer and now I am here again, investigated more deeply and it is turned out gitignore has specific setup in our project. So .DS_Store files are not ignored under a couple of directories only. That is why none of the above did not help(e.g. gitignore has the highest priority over other places like global config or exclude).

Answer (score 5):

Remove ignored files:

(.DS_Store)

```
$ find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

Answer (score 4):

When initializing your repository, skip the git command that contains

```
-u
```

and it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What if someone else created the repo, and OP is only sync'ing with it?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, combo of two answers from above:

- $ git rm --cached -f *.DS_Store
- $ git commit -m "filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached
  --ignore-unmatch .DS_Store"
- $ git push origin master --force

Answer (score 4):

create a `.gitignore` file using command `touch .gitignore`

and add the following lines in it

```
.DS_Store
```

save the `.gitignore` file and then push it in to your git repo.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git commit -m "filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .DS_Store"
$ git push origin master --force
```

Answer (score 3):

add this to your file .gitignore

```
#Ignore folder mac
.DS_Store
```

save this and make commit

```
git add -A
git commit -m "ignore .DS_Store"
```

and now you ignore this for all your commits

Answer (score 2):

No need to remove `.DS_STORE` locally

Just add it to `.gitignore` file

> The .gitignore file is just a text file that tells Git which files or folders to ignore in a project.

Commands

- `nano .gitignore`
- Write `.DS_Store` Then click `CTRL+X > y > Hit Return`
- `git status` To have a last look at your changes
- `git add .gitignore`
- `git commit -m 'YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE'`
- `git push origin master`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions to resolve this problem. 
To avoid creating .DS_Store files, do not to use the OS X Finder to view folders. An alternative way to view folders is to use UNIX command line.
To remove the .DS_Store files a third-party product called DS_Store Terminator can be used.
To delete the .DS_Store files from the entire system a UNIX shell command can be used.
Launch Terminal from Applications:Utilities
At the UNIX shell prompt enter the following UNIX command:
sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;
When prompted for a password enter the Mac OS X Administrator password.

This command is to find and remove all occurrences of .DS_Store starting from the root (/) of the file system through the entire machine.
To configure this command to run as a scheduled task follow the steps below:
Launch Terminal from Applications:Utilities
At the UNIX shell prompt enter the following UNIX command:

sudo crontab -e
When prompted for a password enter the Mac OS X Administrator password.
Once in the vi editor press the letter I on your keyboard once and enter the following:

15 1 * * * root find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;

This is called crontab entry, which has the following format:

Minute Hour DayOfMonth Month DayOfWeek User Command.

The crontab entry means that the command will be executed by the system automatically at 1:15 AM everyday by the account called root.

The command starts from find all the way to . If the system is not running this command will not get executed.

To save the entry press the Esc key once, then simultaneously press Shift + z+ z.

Note: Information in Step 4 is for the vi editor only.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have not been helped by any of the above methods - try to inspect your ***.gitignore*** more thoroughly, it could have some combination of rules between directories and subdirectories so the annoying ***.DS_Store*** files are not ignored in those folders only. For instance you want to ignore ***gensrc*** folders except ones in a ***custom*** directories, so you would have the following ***.gitignore***:

```
.DS_Store
gensrc
!custom/**
```

So with this setup ***any/path/.DS_Store*** ignored, but not ***custom/gensrc/.DS_Store*** and the fix will be moving ***.DS_Store*** entry to the bottom of ***.gitignore*** file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice oneliner to get rid of this for good via global .gitignore file, therefore you will never need this thread again

```
git config --global core.excludesfile "~/.gitignore" &&  echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore
```

This oneliner creates a global .gitignore used by every single repository and all the new ones you create in the future and ignores the .DS_Store file entirely.

Answer (score -1):

I made:

```
git checkout -- ../.DS_Store
```

(# Discarding local changes (permanently) to a file)
And it worked ok!

Comment: If you intend your answer as based on something else (e.g. something that did not work for you) then you need to reference more clearly. Please understand that "above" is not a reliable refernce here, because the display order of answers here is unpredictable. That is among other things because the order policy is configurable.

Answer (score -1):

This method works if you are using the GitHub Desktop app.

1. If not already, open your repository in the app (⌘O)
   [image]
2. From Repository Tab, choose Repository Settings.
   [image]
3. Go to "Ignored files" and add the file(s) you wish to be ignored.
   [image]