# git update-index --assume-unchanged returns "fatal unable to mark file"

Tags: git

I am having the same problem as the OP on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8598937) post, but I don't understand the answer marked as correct (I don't see that it explains how to fix the situation)

I do this and get this error:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged web.config
fatal: Unable to mark file web.config
```

1. The file IS added to the repository
2. It is NOT in `.git/info/exclude`
3. It is NOT in `.gitignore` (it was, but I took it out, then forced
   web.config to be added using `git add -f web.config`, committed, and
   pushed those changes to the repo)
4. When I do `git ls-files -o` it is NOT there

So what can I do to fix?

Comment: re-read the accepted answer in the referenced question: it shall NOT appear in the output of `git ls-files -o`. If so, it's not in the repo.

Comment: my typo, it is NOT in the list, and it is most definitely in the repo

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you, and had followed the same four steps that you indicated above, and had the same results. This included the fact that my file was listed when executing `git ls-files -o`.  However in my case, I also tried executing `git update-index --assume-unchanged` against a file that was not listed when executing `ls-files -o`, and I still received the same error "`fatal: Unable to mark file`".

I thought that perhaps it was a bug, and downloaded the latest version of git, but this did not help.

What I finally realized is that **this command is case sensitive!  This includes the full path and file name.**  After updating path to the directory so that the full path was specified with proper casing, the command executed properly.

Note that this was with Git for Windows, so you're results may vary with other platforms.

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much!  This worked!  I think I was using all lower case before, or cd to the folder and then tried to use this command.

Comment: If the file will change then this is Wrong. The command is a promise, by the user, to Git, that it doesn't have to waste cycles on stating the file to detect if it has changed (for slow file systems;-). Eventually one of the Git commands will notice and you will be suprised. The documentation is being updated to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, this indirectly helped me discover some bad shell script in a project. If a path does not exist, this will fail! :)

Comment: Also note that this command will not work for unversioned files. If you have a file that does not exist in the repository it can be ignored in .gitignore, and boy do I feel silly typing this but I figure it might help somebody as dumb as me. :)

Comment: Just to clarify what some of the comments have hinted at, if you're using a Windows shell that has allowed you to get away with case mismatches in your cds, you will get this error. Either give git the full path to the file (with the correct case), or cd back up and then down again (again, with the correct case at every stage).

Comment: As a complement: you also might encounter the same error facing non-unicode strings path (I got some files named `something à otherthing.csv` which were converted to `something \303\240 otherthing.csv` by `git ls-files`....)

Answer (score 64):

I was having the same issue on a Mac. Case-sensitivity wasn't an issue for me - the problem was I needed to reset my git first:

Problem:

```
 git update-index --assume-unchanged index.php
 fatal: Unable to mark file index.php
```

Solution:

```
git reset HEAD
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   index.php
git update-index --assume-unchanged index.php
```

Comment: I am having the same problem on Mac, and none of the suggested workarounds worked for me. Any idea? I am trying to stop tracking a directory temporarily on my machine only, the name the dir is intellij_idea_project_files/. Apparently all of the files in this directory have been properly marked except one, and that is my_project_name.iml.

Comment: had the same problem and this is the solution that worked for me, not the one about case-sensitive

Comment: I am also on Mac and for me the "solution" was to delete the file. (I would post this as an answer but I'm not sure what happened, maybe later.) Something weird happened. Git was saying the file was changed (I wanted to `--skip-worktree`). I got rid of local changes by running `git restore .` but skip still gave the error. Finally I tried deleting the file. Shockingly, git did not say there was a change. So clearly something funky has happened since git was definitely tracking it and I definitely deleted it and it definitely didn't say that that was a change.

Comment: I am on Git Bash for Windows and this helped me. I didn't even have to run the `update-index` command again after `git reset`

Answer (score 45):

In my case the tree I was marking was a directory, and not a file as in you case, and I was missing the forward slash after its name.

**Incorrect -**

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged directory-name
```

**Correct -**

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged directory-name/
```

***Note*** the forward slash(/) in the end.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this I get "Ignoring path directory-name/"

Comment: @damian Specify full file path instead of the parent directory.

Comment: If I do that I get what damian does. Except my file is a file and not a folder.

Comment: Thanks, this got me past the error and then I found that I needed to add a `*` after the slash for it to ignore all the files in that folder

Comment: It seems that `update-index` doesn't work with directory paths. I wasted half a day to find a solution for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860969

Answer (score 13):

Make sure the file is added to git repo, if not add the file in git repo and then try it will work.

Comment: the OP specifically stated that the file is in the repo

Comment: @FacundoColombier while this answer isn't specific to the OP, I think this is an important answer at this point. This question has received a good amount of attention. So others will come to it looking for a solution to their own specific issue. For instance, this answer solved my problem.

Comment: By "added to git repo", you mean in the current branch, or in any branch? Currently I have the issue that a file exists in one branch, but not the other. File cannot be deleted because it's locked by server. So cannot switch branch since it thinks it would overwrite the file.

Answer (score 7):

fatal: Unable to mark file Localization/el-GR.js

What you can do is:

1. Move to the correct path where the file is present in your local (in GITBASH)
2. Update the index `$git update-index --assume-unchanged <file name>`

This helped me!  :)

Comment: `$ git update-index --assume-unchanged ./.idea/vcs.xml
fatal: Unable to mark file .idea/vcs.xml`
`$ cd .idea`
`git update-index --assume-unchanged .`
Worked, thanks!

Comment: AVProgrammer's solution is what worked for me on OS X

Answer (score 5):

If your path has spaces, you may get this error even if you have the casing right.

This results in the "fatal" error:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged code/Solution Files/WebEssentials-Settings-json
```

To fix it, simply add quotes around the path.

```bash
git update-index --assume-unchanged "code/Solution Files/WebEssentials-Settings-json"
```

Comment: In my case I had the / backwards.

Answer (score 5):

`--assume-unchanged` is about slow file systems, and a users promise that Git doesn't need to check this file, as Git can assume its unchanged. But some command still do check and produce 'surprise'!

Do not use on files which change.

Sorry to be the bringer of that news (I have a patch in process to change that documentation).

Comment: Then how is one supposed to update a file to mark it as 'do not track me' ?

Comment: @javadba see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6964492/717355 'git rm --cached filename'

Comment: thx - upvoted on that: i had actually used it just after posting here. works.

Comment: note that `git rm --cached filename` will delete the file when others pull

Comment: @RyanTaylor yes, it's important for users to realise what their command is saying, which is 'stop tracking this, remove it from my revisions'. Have a read of the latest view of the maintainer, and my new patch.. https://public-inbox.org/git/20161101210448.4692-1-philipoakley@iee.org/T/#u

Comment: @javadba: for that you should use `--skip-worktree`, which is explicitly for preventing git from ever clobbering your local changes to that file, and hides it from the `git status`. Unfortunately, it can have the same issue as this OP, which is why I'm here!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I tried to use any of the methods above, but no luck.

After many attempts, I just thought to add my file to index through.

```
git add myfile.php
```

Git refused this action but he advised me to make it forcibly.

```
git add myfile.php -f
```

And that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

My Problem was, that I tried the command with a * wildcard assuming it would be recursive, but it wasn't.

So what I did was

```
$ git reset HEAD
Unstaged changes after reset: 
M   .gradle/1.9/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
M   .gradle/1.9/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin
M   .gradle/1.9/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
M   .gradle/1.9/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin
M   .gradle/1.9/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
```

executing

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged .gradle/1.9/taskArtifacts/*
```

worked for me then and didn't result in OPs and my problem.

Comment: Addition:
The files need to be listed exactly as they exist in ‘the index’ already. So wildcards need to be resolved by bash already and they cannot match with files not in the index. In my case for temp ignoring btw: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39583010/574370

Answer (score 3):

One common mistake around using this command is trying to assume either not tracked file or ignored file by git already.

Make sure first that the file is tracked by running

```
git ls-files | grep relative_path/to/file
```

If it's not showing your file, then you need to add it first:

```
git add relative_path/to/file
```

If this shows your file, or you've already added that file to git, then you should be able to run git assume commands normally:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree relative_path/to/file
```

or for folders

```
git update-index --skip-worktree relative_path/to/folder/
```

you can check if your file is assumed to be ignored by running

```
git ls-files -v | grep ^S
```

The S character represents skipped files.

Comment: In my case, the file was already in the list of excluded extensions.

Answer (score 3):

So I had this same error when I use this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged appsettings.Development.json
```

So I changed it to

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged appsettings.development.json
```

I actually tried many methods at first but I ended up using this. So I guess its case sensitive

Comment: You have two same pieces of code

Comment: The case is different

Comment: Make sense now.

Answer (score 3):

**stage** your file, only after that run `--assume-unchanged`, then **unstage** the file

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have "web.config" checked in.

If it isn't,  you will get this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was trying to untrack *.orig files.

This is what I did to untrack them:

```
$git reset -- *.orig
```

if that doesn't work:

```
$git clean -fd
```

Comment: It's dangerous to ask people to execute command without telling them that this command will delete files.     $git clean -fd

Comment: I was stupid enough to run the command before your comment Rathore. All my files deleted!!

Comment: Should remove the command that deletes files!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe useful for someone.
I had the same problem and was no syntax problem, no name with spaces, no path problem, and git reset command didn't work. I was commiting from a folder inside apache www and apache service was stopped. Started again apache service and the error is gone

Answer (score 1):

I found that sometimes this doesn't work because you've already committed the file to your .gitignore and made a push or pull. You only need to make the push and your file should be ignored on subsequent commits even when you locally modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

For all future visitors. None of the above resolved my issue. 
What I realized is the `.gitignore` file must be placed in the right directory. In my case, once I moved `.gitignore` to application's root directory the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file to be marked exists and spells correctly, especially the file path and file separator. The file separators of windows system and linux system are in different directions.

Comment: While not wrong, this answer doesn't really add anything to the question. All your suggestions have already been brought up in existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, nothing else worked (my file was tracked, and NOT in gitignore). I realised I copied the file name from terminal output a few lines above, and that made it copy the blank space AFTER the file name. Even though it looks like there is no space, I had a lot of space at the end. So copying just the file path, and keeping it in double qoutes, that helped.
I also did a `git reset HEAD` first.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged "app/src/main/java/com/username/projectName/Utils.kt"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was getting the `fatal: Unable to mark file` error because i had pushed the file to my git repo, so git was not able to find it, first make sure you commit and push the template file that you want to keep in github but do not track it later.

Once pushed, now you can run the command `git update-index --skip-worktree YOUR_FILE` and modify it without this being tracked

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because copying and pasting, the double dashes became an em dash "—assume-unchanged" instead of this "--assume-unchanged".

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are unignoring (`--no-assume-unchanged`) the file from the same path that you ran the initial ignore (`--assume-unchanged`) command.

I ignored the file `d.txt` while in path `a/b/c`, e.g. `git update-index --assume-unchanged d.txt`, but on moving to `a/`, I could not use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged ./b/c/d.txt`, instead receiving the 'fatal: unable to mark file' message.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with cygwin in windows. Giving the full file path