# git update-index --assume-unchanged not working for me

Tags: git

I am in a project building a web app. We use Git for version control and Gulp for task automation. I would like to temporarily ignore files to a certain folder, the build folder. We tend to commit changes to that folder at the end of the day (or at the end of a coding session).

After some research I found the following command to start ignoring changes to a file:
`$ git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`

When I run that code to ignore the build folder I see on the terminal: `Ignoring path build/`

But it still shows changes not staged for that folder so that I have to run `git checkout -- build/` before each commit.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using git 2.9.3 on a PC with elementary OS (Ubuntu-based distro).

Comment: I personally add a .gitignore file to any directory whose contents I want to ignore.  In the .gitignore file, adding `" ./* "` ignores all files in that directory.  Also, something like `" ./somedir/* "` will ignore anything in the subdirectory /firstdir/somedir but still stage any other changes under /firstdir/.  Not quite the automatic process you may be wanting, but that's how I've done it.  Hope it helps somehow

Comment: @SomeDude Thanks. But I am looking for an alternative without using .gitignore.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're not supposed to change the file with that bit.

> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, **the user promises not to change the file** and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index.

It's intended to save time on big projects.

> This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).

I think you're looking for `--[no-]skip-worktree`

> When one of these flags is specified, the object name recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, these options set and unset the "skip-worktree" bit for the paths.

Usage:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file>
```

Start tracking again:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file>
```

You might forget what you have skipped, so I have an alias created:

```
[alias]
    skipped = !git ls-files -v | grep --color "^S"
```

Comment: I have tried the above and assume unchanged but nothing works, It gives me this error always `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:` the only option i see is to delete the file and save it somewhere then only it allows me to pull... Please help

Comment:  ```git update-index --skip-worktree <file>``` works like a charm! Thanks boss.

Comment: I tried both, --assume-unchanged and --skip-worktree. Both commands succeeded but have no effect. git status still reports the folder I want to remove from the list of untracked files as untracked.

Answer (score -2):

We can use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file
```

to start ignoring changes to a file
and

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file
```

to track file again

Comment: I don't believe this is an answer to the question. The OP was having trouble with the first command you listed and the second command isn't a solution to their problem, it only details how to undone the first. The accepted answer explains how `--assume-unchanged` isn't what the OP should use for their intended purpose.