# git update-index --assume-unchanged vcs.xml - fatal

Tags: git

I get the following error with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged vcs.xml
fatal: Unable to mark file .idea/vcs.xml
```

and can't resolve this fatal error.

I had a read of this question [git update-index --assume-unchanged returns "fatal unable to mark file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920652/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-returns-fatal-unable-to-mark-file)

but none of the solutions worked. I noticed someone else had this problem in one of the comments so it may be a specific problem related to `.idea/vcs.xml`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will get this error if the file is not in the index (i.e., is untracked, and possibly also ignored). Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged .idea/vcs.xml
```