# Unable to mark file in git

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to ignore the changes made to .gitignore file. For achieving this I am using this command `git update-index --assume-unchanged bin/.gitignore` on git bash.

When I execute, I see `Unable to mark file bin/.gitignore` response on my git bash.

> How to solve this and why am I facing this problem?

I tried this link too but didn't help

**[git update-index --assume-unchanged returns "fatal unable to mark file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920652/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-returns-fatal-unable-to-mark-file)**

Comment: are you sure the given relative path correct? is `bin/.gitignore` file under your CWD?

Comment: @Kent Yes I have used correct path and it is under CWD.

Comment: if the path is correct, has the file already been in git stage? If it was never added, you got error too

Comment: simply, pls report the output of cmd: `git ls-files  --error-unmatch /yourPath/file`

Comment: I know that doesn't help with your current problem, but if you want to locally exclude files, put their patterns into `.git/info/exclude`. That file will never be committed and is perfectly suited for telling git to ignore some files only in this work tree.

Comment: Had the same problem with app.config. The filename is case sensitive. Using App.config as it was in git solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after talking in comments and getting more information, I am posting this as an answer.

Very likely the cause is, the file you want to set `assume-unchanged` bit was not tracked by git. In comment, I mention the command:

```
git ls-files --error-unmatch /yourPath/file
```

Which you can check if a file is tracked by git.

If it is not tracked, you cannot update the index, since it is not indexed yet. You can just add it to your `.gitignore` file, so that it will be ignored by git.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your file's relative path is correct.

Try this:

```
$ pwd                        # see working directory 
$ ls -la ./bin/              # see if .gitignore file exist!
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged ./bin/.gitignore
```

And also see if your `bin/.gitignore` file is listed in `git ls-files -o`.

```
$ git ls-files -o    # Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
```

If `.gitignore` file is found then `add`, `commit`. Then try `undate-index`.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Message'

$ git update-index --assume-unchanged ./bin/.gitignore
```

Comment: Committing something worked for me, but I have no idea why? Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I think your .gitignore is untracked file. Check it using **git status**. If it is untracked one you won't be able to **update-index** for that file.
Better add and commit then **update-index**
or physically delete it and then pull the changes from your repo.