# .gitignore not ignoring .idea path

Tags: git, gitignore

What am I missing that needs to be done in order to get `git` to ignore my `.idea/` path?

```
ctote@ubuntu:~/dev/1$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .idea/.name
    modified:   .idea/misc.xml
    modified:   .idea/modules.xml
    modified:   .idea/vcs.xml
    modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
    modified:   src/Receiver.java
    modified:   test/1/agent/WindowsQueryHandlerTest.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    lib/
    mp1.iml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

---

```
ctote@ubuntu:~/dev/1$ cat .gitignore
*.class

# Package Files #
*.war
*.ear

# IDEA config files
.idea/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: simply the files can be ignored - any folder any file you want to ignore - go to intellij tool , right click on file/folder --> git --> add ti .gitignore file , that's it -from then onwards intellij will start ignoring these files/folder for changes

Answer (score 511, accepted):

`.gitignore` only ignores newly added (untracked) files.

If you have files that have already been added to the repository, all their changes will be tracked as usual, even if they are matched by .gitignore rules.

To remove that folder from the repository (without deleting it from disk), do:

```
git rm --cached -r .idea
```

Comment: fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files

Comment: I am also getting the above fata: pathspec... error message

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns Do you have an .idea folder that's committed/staged to git?

Comment: LGTM, I also got the same errors as specified above, but I did force remove using `-f`. Thank you.

Comment: ive been looking for this for a long time. Works. Thank!

Comment: $ git rm --cached -r .idea
fatal: pathspec '*.idea' did not match any files

Comment: The last argument should be the path to the `.idea` directory. If it's not at the top level of the project, you'll need to specify that - for example `git rm --cached -r util/.idea`

Comment: This single sentence helps a lot: ".gitignore only ignores newly added (untracked) files. "
Thank you ! for now, I realize a coworker checked in temporary files that were driving me nut ! I'll just git rm them and do a commit.

Answer (score 56):

add `.idea/` to .gitignore file

run this commands in terminal to complete mission :)

```
git rm -rf .idea
git commit -m "delete .idea"
git push
```

Comment: fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files

Comment: @MartinErlic
please, cd project root first and run that commands

Answer (score 27):

To remove the **"fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files"** just use if the dir still returns as untracked:

`git clean -f -d .idea`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me out of everything.

Comment: This deletes the folder from your file system!

Answer (score 19):

#### Remove the file from the repository run below command

```
git rm --cached .idea/
```

#### now update your gitignore file to ignore .idea folder run below command

```
echo '.idea' >> .gitignore
```

#### add the .gitignore file

```
git add .gitignore

git commit -m "Removed .idea files"
```

Comment: Start with git rm -r --cached .idea/ to avoid/solve "fatal: not removing '.idea/' recursively without -r"

Comment: And for those who are working like me with IntelliJ Community Edition or Android Studio: Do EVERYTHING including the "git commit …"  outside the IDE using the command line of something like the Git Bash shell. Only after that the already added files in the .idea folder disappear from Intellij's commit dialog.

Answer (score 10):

For those of you getting `fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files`:

You just have to include the full path to the .idea folder.

So first, do a `git status`, which should show you the path to `.idea` given where you currently are.

Then, include the path in the command w0lf suggested: `git rm --cached -r example/path/to/.idea`

Answer (score 9):

If, after following steps from other answers, you still find that your instance of git running in bash or powershell just keeps on tracking the .idea/ folder, then try this!

I discovered that Jet Brains IDE's have their own .gitignore, and run their own instance of git that will override your .gitignore settings!

What I did to fix this was to navigate to /.idea/.gitignore, and change its contents to:

```
/**
```

so as to ignore everything in the folder.

The image below shows how you can navigate to the .gitignore file from within your Jetbrains IDE.

[image: Locating .gitignore]

Comment: This is what worked for me. I had not commited the .idea folder.

Comment: This is what worked. Even after running `git clean` and adding the `.idea` folder to `.gitignore`, the files would get added back. I'm guessing due to conflicts between the two `.gitignore` files? This solution fixed that.

Answer (score 6):

Well, with all the nice solutions mentioned above, none of them worked for me because here was the mistake I did. I ignored those settings during project creation itself!

1. There were 2 `.gitignore` files i failed to notice and update the project level file.

[image]

2. Since, I had already committed those files/paths during the project creation, they always had a delta from remote after each build command; despite being added in `.gitignore`.

#### Solution

- I focussed on issue 2 and deleted those folder/directories from remote first.
- Took a pull on local.
- Viola! No more tracking of ignored files!

Answer (score 4):

1. Make changes in .gitignore file and save.
2. Open CMD as admin or Terminal and go to Project folder.
3. Run `git rm -r --cached .idea/`
4. Run `git add .`
5. Run `git commit -m "chore: Rider files ignored."`

For details, see [how to fix gitignore](https://sigalambigha.home.blog/2020/03/11/how-to-refresh-gitignore/)

In my case, my .gitignore has those lines:

```js
### Rider ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio, WebStorm and Rider
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml
.idea/.idea.TemplateProject/.idea/indexLayout.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# auto-import.
# .idea/artifacts
# .idea/compiler.xml
# .idea/jarRepositories.xml
# .idea/modules.xml
# .idea/*.iml
# .idea/modules
# *.iml
# *.ipr

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```

Comment: you are right but don't apply "git rm -r --cached <directory>" like "cache refresh". It could be dangerous for some cases.

Comment: Can you give an example where that causes problems?

Answer (score 1):

To Solve Error **"fatal: pathspec '.idea' did not match any files"** after entering above command,

1. Check the path of your idea folder and its files.
2. For this do `git status`. It will list all the files as usual. Check the path of idea folder files. Mine was at `../.idea/workspace.xml`. Notice the `../.idea`
3. Modify the above suggested command in the accepted answer to  `git rm --cached -r ../.idea`
4. You will then see this `rm '.idea/workspace.xml'` and the files will be removed.

Comment: @AlexTotheroh yeah seems same. Just tried to help others with the exact steps I took in my project to solve this.

Comment: I have the same problem here. `.gitignore` is inside the module directory not the project directory. I tried `../.idea`, however, it didn't work. It's still suggesting that I should keep track of files inside `.idea`

Answer (score 1):

For ignoring `.idea` folder and `iml` file types, I did the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, moving .gitignore to the root of my project saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750606/git-still-shows-files-as-modified-after-adding-to-gitignore/65390604#65390604) if git status still shows .idea even if .idea/* is already added in your .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above solutions here and none of them worked.

What worked for me was that I added `.idea` to both .gitignore files. (As of the latest update there is a separate `.gitignore` file inside the `.idea` folder)

Then I just deleted whichever files were shown in the commit message and undo'ed the delete. That seemed to clear it from the git cache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my situation is slightly different, because my `.idea` directory was already staged for commit, but I just followed the advice given in the git status output to run `git restore --staged <file>...`:

```
C:\Devstuff\proj01>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage) <<< THIS HERE
        new file:   .idea/.gitignore
        new file:   .idea/proj01.iml
        new file:   .idea/modules.xml
        new file:   .idea/vcs.xml

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .idea/proj01.iml
        modified:   file/that/was/changed.js
```

So I ran:

```
C:\Devstuff\proj01>git restore --staged .idea/
```

And after that it was sorted:

```
C:\Devstuff\proj01>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   webapp/controller/Master.controller.js
```