# Remove directory/file from Git cache using GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I know I can do this from the command line via
[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384473/gitignore-not-ignoring-idea-path) but I want this first world problem solved of being able to do it via the GUI

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found an exact equivalent to `git rm --cached`, but I found how to ignore a tracked file/directory and remove it from cache at the same time (which is often what I need):

- Right-click on file/directory > `Ignore` > Choose a pattern

[image]

- Select `Ignore and Stop Tracking`

[image]