# how to gitignore config folder in laravel

Tags: git, laravel

I am working on a laravel project and we have separate settings for database.php in local and on server and I want to ignore this file but when I am adding this line in gitignore database.php still shows in git status

```
/config/database.php
```

I also tried

```
config/database.php
```

but does not work so any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `.gitignore` doesn’t affect already tracked files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: You need to clear the tracked file from cache as described in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9750651/1272406

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to ignore the config files, rather have separate `.env` files for development and production. Read the values from the `.env` files into your config like:

```
'db_password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
```

Set the value for `DB_PASSWORD` in the `.env` files like:

```
DB_PASSWORD=12345
```

Comment: The issue is that file comes up again and again for git status and if i do not commit it then changes get reverted and I have to add my changes again.. that is a pain point