# How do i ignore directories in .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

**Hey everyone! I am writing a new project right now and i have some problems with ignoring build directories.** [image: Project main directory]

**I need to ignore out/ directory but it doesn't work. (I already deleted out/ directory from my github repository)**

**This is .gitignore line:**

[image: .gitignore file]

**This is github repository after i deleted out/ directory from it**

[image: Github repository]

**Looks like it should work, but after all this out/ directory still appears in commit list:**

[image]

**How should i do this?**

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text, especially when that's all there is in the picture. It breaks the StackOverflow search engine.

Comment: Just write `out` in your gitignore.

Comment: @MSalters Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @BNilsou it also doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure whether `.gitignore` is whitespace-sensitive or not, but try removing the space before `out/`.

Comment: You can use git `rm -r --cached out`
Answer reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750606/git-still-shows-files-as-modified-after-adding-to-gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also doing `git rm -r --cached out`