# How I can add some files to git ignore if that files are indexed?

Tags: eclipse, gitignore

I want to add files starting with dot to .gitignore file.
also this files was to add to indexed. Here is some image from terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAzlj.png)

[files which i need to add to gitignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn6sl.jpg)

[try to add files to gitignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juw7N.jpg)

Comment: I use the following trick for this: move the file to ignore to a different folder so that the deletion of these files can be committed and then moving the files back, git-ignoring them and do an _Amend_ commit of the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750606/git-still-shows-files-as-modified-after-adding-to-gitignore/9750651#9750651