# Git ignore push only

Tags: git

Is there a way with git to ignore local changes to a file but continue tracking it into the remote repo ?
I wan't to fetch but not push a file.

In my case, I want the .project eclipse file to be committed the first time on the "master" repo, but the dev team doesn't have to push changes made by eclipse plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git ignore files only locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not an official way, this is the workflow we use:

Rename and add add `.example` at the end of the filename.

Add the actual filename to your `.gitignore` file (and commit the `.gitignore` file).

Locally, copy the file to a copy that has the actual filename (now being ignored).

Comment: So, there is no official way to do that.