# How to use gems locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I would like to use gems `'better_errors'` and `'binding_of_caller'` for my debugging in rails app, but i DON'T want to include those in `Gemfile`. Is it possible to do? My first thought was to simply

```
gem install better_errors
gem install binding_of_caller
```

but it doesnt work, i mean installation finishes without problems, but thats it, gem doesnt seem to work at all when i run my app on localhost. Do I need some kind of config set, anybody?

Comment: Why don't you want to include them in your gemfile?

Comment: reference a local gem with git if you happen to be working on it.

Comment: @Baloo i dont want to force those gems on my coworkers. KRUKUSA any more details?

Comment: If I did get you, why not simply `bundle exec gem install <your gem name>` ?

Answer (score 1):

> but i DON'T want to include those in Gemfile. Is it possible to do?

Yes, it is possible. You can just download the respective directories in desire folder (ex. `lib`) and add that gem class in your initializer so it will be loaded at the time of starting. Configuration varies as per gem.

> My first thought was to simply .... but it doesnt work,

Ofcourse, it wont. How can your rails app magically detects without knowing it that you have better way to show error. It is simply saying like you have `cancer` formula and doctors automatically applied that formula to there patient without you telling them. There should be some commucaition between two parties rails-app and gem so they can coordinate  and work better.

> Do I need some kind of config set, anybody?

Yes, explained above.

> i dont want to force those gems on my coworkers. KRUKUSA any more details? // said in comment

Yes, including this gems in your rails app can do this job. This extension will be available automatically to your worked. (no force applied :P)

**it looks like all you want to not show those gems to other co-worker**, if so, you can use this trick with [git](/questions/tagged/git).

To achieve this thing, first simply add the gems in your gemfile, run `bundle` and then make it untrackable with git. You can put  `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` in your `.gitignore` file. or you can add the first add the gems and mark it ignore with below command. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally)

```
 git update-index --assume-unchanged Gemfile Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: I didn't test its validity but nice answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to create your own environment and use it accordingly.

1. Have your own configuration for `myenv`:

   ```
   $ cp config/environments/{development,myenv}.rb
   ```
2. In `config/database.yml`, add the environment `myenv` and use the same config as `development`:

   ```
   development: &development
     <rest of the code you have on config/databases.yml>
     ...

   myenv:
     << *development
   ```
3. In `Gemfile` add your custom gems to use on your `mydev` group:

   group :myenv do
     gem 'better_errors'
     gem 'binder_of_caller'
   end
4. Run rails and rake with `RAILS_ENV` like this: `RAILS_ENV=myenv rails c`

The advantage of this approach is that you still get the updates from `Gemfile` from the repo, and if you need to add a gem in the `Gemfile` for everybody to see, you still can.

Also, nobody will see the gems you installed inside the `myenv` group in your Gemfile.