# git ignore whole folder excluding one file

Tags: git

Hey this does not work for me:

```
vendor/*
!vendor/predis/
vendor/predis/*
!vendor/predis/predis
vendor/predis/predis/*
!vendor/predis/predis/lib
vendor/predis/predis/lib/*
!vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis
vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/*
!vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile
vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile/*
!vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile/ServerVersion24.php
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I'm perfectly able to reinclude a file in a subfolder as you are trying to do. Your mistake must lay somewhere else, for example a typo in some folder name which is impossible to diagnose for us.

Comment: It should be some sort of configuration in my git. The path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your actual state of the repository?

I believe that what you want to have is just:

```
vendor/*
```

Prior to creating `.gitignore` file, just `git add vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile/ServerVersion24.php`. It will now be tracked.

After you create `.gitignore` file (or add the mentioned line to it) all **untracked** files in `vendor` directory will be ignored.

**[EDIT]** (Correction after helpful comments, thanks!)

Please keep in mind that you cannot ignore a file that is already tracked. If you want to do that, you need execute command `git update-index --assume-unchanged` against the files you want to ignore - but this change will be local to your repository, it will not be shared. For more details see [How to ignore files only locally in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally).

Comment: `.git/info/exclude` is in no way different to `.gitignore` except for the fact that it only exists for your local repository. It doesn't enable you to ignore already tracked files as you implied.

Comment: See `git help update-index`, specifically the option `--assume-unchanged` for how to ignore changes to a tracked file.

Comment: My mistake, updating my answer (as it was a side note, not the core of it).

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer, @Chepner, unfortunately the --assume-unchanged is not about ignoring the file, it's merely an indication to Git that you won't be changing it, so it doesn't need to expend cycles in some code paths to stat the files. Other commands will still notice the changes and do things you don't expect. The git documentation is being updated in the current change cycle. Try `--skip-worktree`.

Answer (score 0):

create `.gitignore` with

```
vendor/*
```

then `git add -f vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile/ServerVersion24.php`

the `-f` option will ignore the rules in `.gitignore`, so the file will be tracked

Comment: fatal: Path 'vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile/ServerVersion24.php' is in submodule 'vendor/predis/predis'

Comment: @hellomyfriends That's your problem: The file you are trying to track rests in a submodule. You can't seperatly track files in submodules. What are you trying to achieve then?