# How to ignore a file locally?

Tags: git

So there is this configuration xml file, that for some unknown reason if I don't add a couple of extra lines of code my project wont work, however it works for everyone else.

The thing is, I can't commit/push this file, but since the file is staged I can't pull or push either...

One solution would be to stash/pop all the time, but it's annoying.

Does anyone know if there is a command or something to somehow tell Git to ignore this file local changes or something like that?.

So when I do a pull that particular file wont be modified, and when I do a push that file will count as up to date, without changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git ignore files only locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally)

Comment: In the OP it says the he has "untracked files", however my config file is not untracked, it exists in the repository, will that solution still work?.