# How to tell git to ignore changes in certain files, but not to put them in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some files that are part of a project that have some minor modifications from their source in the repository to control settings specific to my development environment.

They are constantly listed as "modified" and are always left unstaged.

These files do not belong in a .gitignore, as far as I am aware, since they belong in the repository. I would like git to basically ignore the fact that they have been modified.

This must be a common scenario, and I am looking for the best-practice way to handle it.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally

I will leave the question here, in case anyone else has any other insight though.

Comment: If they are for your specific development environment I would argue that they shouldn't be in your repo.

Comment: @Jared There are general config files that have small changes to paths and urls in a few places, specific to my development environment. Ideally these configurations should be set at runtime by env variables, but that's just not how it is.

Comment: .git/info/exclude?

Comment: You could also use a hook like `pre-commit` to implement it. But of course it's not so convenient as the exclude or ignore way. Just FYI. But it does work after you have added these files into the git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [git ignoring](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) documentation.

Generally, you have three options:

1. a global ignore file, specified in the global `core.excludesfile` setting.
2. a per-repository `.git/info/exclude`, not shared with other repo instances (and thus, other team members)
3. a regular `.gitignore` in a given location of the source tree.