# Git How to ignore modified folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using Windows 10. Below is my folder structure.

```
Test
    -> Test2 -> Test3
    -> .gitignore
```

**.gitignore**

```
Test2/Test3
```

Would like to igone Test3 locally. It has modified files. So it's till showing. It's already there in `.gitignore`.

Still it's showing on `git status`

Comment: If you want to ignore only locally, use `.git/info/exclude` instead of `.gitignore`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally

Comment: In exclude folder what needs to put?. Not able to create `.git` directory it says Invalid file type

Comment: You can't ignore modified files.  You can only ignore files that aren't in the repository already, which is to say that a `.gitignore` or a `.git/info/exclude` can only affect files in the `added` state, never in the `modified` state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove git cache by

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

And then add files again will work fine

```
git add .
```

Comment: How to undo above commands? I have some issue

Comment: What's the issue you have? There will not be any issue after you `git add .`

Answer (score -1):

Local files that you want git to ignore can be set in .git/info/exclude (similar to .gitignore).