# Include own git repo to external git versioned project

Tags: git, git-submodules

I read about the possibility to integrate external git repositories with submodules:

```
# file .gitmodules
[submodule "other"]
    path = other
    url = git@github.com:foobar/other.git
```

I want to do this vice versa. There is a git versioned open source project which I cloned locally. I want to work on this project, maybe make some commits and pull requests there.

First I want to develop an own module for that system and therefore I need to create an new folder within the project. For my own code I want to use git too.

To develop fast and see my changes immediately on my local dev machine I don't want to split their git repo and mine but use both parallel. So I can't change their `.gitignore` or `.gitmodules` with my stuff.

How can I integrate my git submodule without touching files of the main project?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the directory that your module uses using the `.git/info/exclude` file, which uses the same syntax as `.gitignore`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753078/5287638) for more details on how it works.

You can't use git submodules, as they are specifically designed to keep one project in sync with the other one (if you make a commit in the submodule, you have to make a corresponding commit in the main git repository or the changes show up as untracked).