# How to properly handle a file only used locally in git?

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I want to reorder the output of changed files in git commits so I've created a file called `submodule/orderfile` and configured [`diff.orderFile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to point to that file.

Now many problems arise

- If I add the file to `.gitignore`, the `.gitignore` will be listed as modified
- If I add the path `submodule/orderfile` to `.git/info/exclude` the file still appears when I run `git status`.

Either way, `orderfile` or `.gitignore` will be listed in git status. If I commit it to a branch it'll be removed when I switch to another branch. I don't want to push those files because I only use them locally.

I tried to run `git update-index --assume-unchanged orderfile` like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753078/995714) but it gives

```
fatal: Unable to mark file orderfile
```

More importantly even if I can manage to ignore the file, it'll be removed when I run `git clean -xdf`

So how can I told git to not track the file and still leave it as-is when I run `git clean -xdf`?

Comment: How about moving the file out of the repository and configuring `diff.orderFile` to the new path?

Answer (score 0):

> How about moving the file out of the repository and configuring diff.orderFile to the new path?

That was my first thought, but [diff.orderFile](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-difforderFile) is  a relative pathname, it is treated as relative to the top of the working tree.
Maybe ../afile would work.

An alternative is to define a `git` wrapper script which calls `git`, but with the [-O](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Oltorderfilegt)  option when using `diff`.
That way, you can really place the orderfile outside the repo.

Comment: `If diff.orderFile is a relative pathname, it is treated as relative to the top of the working tree.` I think it can work if an absolute path is used here.