# Do not sync versioning file in git

Tags: git, versioning, git-remote, ignore

I'm working on a C++ project using git. Since we all use different IDE we all have our own project files. But I don't want to change the files added to the project all the time I switch the branch. So is there a way to have the project file in the versioning but never push it to the remote?

Comment: Why not put them in `.gitignore`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-to-ignore-files-only-locally-in-git

Comment: a .gitignore and as far as i understood the problem from the link the exclude will simply ignore the files from commits. I use them but that's not what i'm looking for. I want the vs project file being part of the  repository. So on every commit I may changed the project file and that should be saved. But I don't want this to be uploaded. So commit yes, push no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way of doing what you want

When you want to switch of branch, before switching you can use the command :

> git stash

this command creates a LOCAL commit, that will never be puched, it's like a commit -am "nothing"  but only versionned locally

after that you can use :

> git checkout your_branch

when you return to the fist branch :

> git checkout bnach_1

you can re-merge the local modifications done before switching by doing

> git stash pop

There is more options on git stash available [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: This comes closer to my problem, but when i stash the project file it is gone. and i want to keep it locally. So when i do a commit i want the project file saved too, like all the other files. But i never want to push it