# Remove modified file from git

Tags: git

I have a problem with removing modified files from git. When I do `git status`, it shows list of modified file which are not require to commit.

Comment: You want the file removed from the git repo and ignored moving forward?

Comment: More context?!? Or a better explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you need an answer then [edit] the question and put more information in it. The output of `git status` together with what exactly you want, what you did and what doesn't work as you expect is a minimum that could change the question from a candidate to closing into a successful question.

Comment: A "modified" file is one that has been added to the repository and then was changed. Untracked files are ones that have not been added to the repository. You should update your `.gitignore` to exclude files that you want to be ignored for consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore somes files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-somes-files-locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should add .gitignore in your repo to be accidentally commit such unwanted files.

You can remove all unwanted modified files using below git command :

***git checkout -f***