# Excluding files from localgit repo

Tags: wordpress, git

I am working on a Wordpress site, and been given access to the git repository for this project. The entire WP install is in the Repo. All I care about is being able to push my changes to the theme and a select list of plugin folders, ie:

```
/wp-content/themes/myTheme2017/
/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin1/
/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin2/
....
```

How can I exclude everything else from being tracked? How can I update my local WP install, and customize my wp-config.php file, and not have those changes be tracked?

As per [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally), I can specify the files I want excluded much like in gitignore files. Then, I can run `git update-index --skip-worktree [<file>...]` and get my desired results.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree wp-config.php
```

The real question is then can I exclude entire folders? Do I have to run the skip-worktree command on every file?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this question? >>  [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: I can't use gitinore because the files and directories are in the repository. I need to use exclude somehow, but I'm not finding much info on it. Re: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: oic. looks to me that you need to separate your code out of the main repo by using git submodule.

Comment: @chawarong can you give more details? thank you for your time

Comment: @VonC has already answered that. I also find this link helpful. [Working with submodules](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The real question is then can I exclude entire folders? Do I have to run the skip-worktree command on every file?

Yes, every file: Git does work with *content* (files), not containers (directories).

You can find here [an approach using submodules](https://deliciousbrains.com/git-submodules-manage-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)

```
git submodule add -f https://github.com/wp-plugins/wp-migrate-db.git ./wp-content/plugins/wp-migrate-db
git commit -m "Added WP Migrate DB plugin"
```

That allows to commit separately in your parent repo or your submodule.