# Running bundle or rspec adds line to Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, gemfile.lock

After running various commands (bundle and rspec for example) in a Ruby project, `Gemfile.lock` is updated and `x86_64-darwin-17` is added to the `PLATFORMS` heading. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Running `gem env` gives this interesting context:

```
○ → gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-darwin17]
  #...etc  
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? `Gemfile.lock` is designed to make your gem environment reproducible. If it's being updated it just means that you're running with a different environment than you were previously e.g. if one of your gems was updated to have a new dependency.

Comment: It's a project that I've recently joined with multiple other contributors. Their system info isn't listed there. I've got the correct ruby and bundler version so I don't want to check this change into git.

Comment: This happens to me all the time, and I just try not to commit them. Not a great solution, but I'm in the habit of always checking my changes before I commit or push so it hasn't be a problem.

Comment: What is your issue exactly? if you run `bundle`, then the gems specified in your `Gemfile` will be installed, and the versions of all these gems will be specified your `Gemfile.lock`. Running rspec shouldn't affect the state of your bundle.

Comment: I added an answer. There was a global bundler config which was responsible for the behavior. Whether or not running rspec is supposed to touch the lockfile, it was updating it unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by global bundler config. Setting to false stopped the behavior.

> specific_platform (BUNDLE_SPECIFIC_PLATFORM): Allow bundler to resolve for the specific running platform and store it in the lockfile, instead of only using a generic platform. A specific platform is the exact platform triple reported by Gem::Platform.local, such as x86_64-darwin-16 or universal-java-1.8. On the other hand, generic platforms are those such as ruby, mswin, or java. In this example, x86_64-darwin-16 would map to ruby and universal-java-1.8 to java.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @RangerRanger didn't work for me but I checked in the [bundler doc](https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html) as he did and find this who worked for me:

> force_ruby_platform (BUNDLE_FORCE_RUBY_PLATFORM): Ignore the current machine's platform and install only ruby platform gems. As a result, gems with native extensions will be compiled from source.

Here is the command: `bundle config force_ruby_platform true`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install dependencies without updating the `Gemfile.lock`, just use the [`--frozen` option](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html). e.g. `bundle --frozen`. This will install dependencies normally, except not update the `Gemfile.lock`

#### Edit

If this is not a good solution, probably the best bet is going to be adding the `Gemfile.lock` to a `.gitignore` specific to your local repo.
You can create one at `your_repo/.git/info/exclude` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753078/2230115)

Comment: I appreciate the idea but this occurs in more cases than running bundle. For instance, the line is added after running rspec tests.

Comment: .gitignore is probably what you're looking for then. you can have one specific to only your local repo.

Comment: As far as I can tell `bundle exec rspec` shouldn't update the gemfile.lock. I've never seen that happen to me..

Another possible solution is to alias `bundle` -> `bundle --frozen`