# Can't install devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bundler

I'm attempting to install devise_token_auth. The instructions say to add `gem 'devise_token_auth'`
to my Gemfile, then run `bundle install`. I created a brand new API only Rails app, follow the instructions, and get the following:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 6.1.1) x86_64-darwin-20

    devise_token_auth x86_64-darwin-20 was resolved to 0.1.21.alpha2, which depends on
      rails (~> 4.1.4)
```

What is `x86_64-darwin-20`? That's not in the Gemfile, but I'm working on MacOS. What's going on?

Comment: That looks like an old version of `devise_token_auth`. That version was realeased in 2014 so it is quite old. I think 1.1.4 is the newest version and likely won't have any issues, if you specify that in the Gemfile, with your version of Rails. https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_token_auth/versions .  That other bit about the platform info `x86_64-darwin-20` might be answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765393/running-bundle-or-rspec-adds-line-to-gemfile-lock

Comment: That seemed to do it. Seems like devise_token_auth v1.1.4 needs rails  >= 4.2.0, < 6.1, so I just specified gem 'rails', '6.0'. I wish I could give your comment the answer, is there a way to do so? I'm new to this.

Comment: No there isn't.  It's cool, glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Rockwell Rice:
https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_token_auth/versions/1.1.4 shows you the dependencies.

devise_token_auth depends on rails  >= 4.2.0, < 6.1. So I just recreated a new rails app with version 6.0.

Comment: But thats not a solution. Is there any major difference rolled out in rails 6.1.1 which makes device auth token gem stuck at current version?
Has any one patched it?
I wish device_aoth_token have a patch to work with rails 6.1.1