# How to pull from remote, while locally ignoring file?

Tags: git

In git, I ignored locally file using .git/info/exclude, based on answer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally). But now I can not pull from remote, this is the error that I am getting:

```
git pull 

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by 
merge: ignoredFile

Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

So I tried commit this file:

```
git commit -am "Message"


On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 4 commits, and can be fast- 
forwarded.
    (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So question is as in title, how to keep repository updated (git pull), while ignoring particular files locally.

EDIT:
I ran commend:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged ignoredFile
```

Before git pull.

EDIT2:

```
git pull --rebase


error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    ignoredFile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 0f37f00b..5ccc1b0a
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    ignoredFile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting could not detach HEAD
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Comment: Why would you ignore the local changes?

Comment: I have some maven configuration that is more convenient to me, but I do not want to pollute team's repo.

Comment: The configuration files should not stay in the source control. There should be a template or sample file in the repository and the name of the real file (manually created from the template/sample) added to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for:

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

This will update your branch and move your changes ahead without creating a new branch, but not ignore your local files so that if required you could either push them or create a branch from it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite hard, if not impossible (without some major hackery). In `git`, operations like `merge`etc. (basically, almost all except `git add`) work on the whole tree by design; while there are some more or less arcane ways to change this, it is certainly not the most everyday thing.

If I may suggest another direction: you mention that you use this to fix some Maven settings which are local/specific for you. Instead of hacking around with git, find an official way to have local bits in your Maven configuration. Maven as [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for example, which should readily be able to fix your problem. It also supports (de)referencing environment variables, which might give you some more options.