# How to avoid a file in a pull request with git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

When cloning a Rails repository I have to update the mysql2 gem localy to a newer version for it to run on my machine. When creating a branch and then pull request with my changes how do I avoid adding the changed gem into the pull request?

Comment: You can stash it via `git stash` or removing from tracking or adding it to .gitignore file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. git fetch
```

This will get the latest from your remote

```
2. git merge origin/master
```

This will merge your remote master to your current branch

```
3. git reset --soft origin/master
```

This will reset your commits based on current origin/master. So all the changes that you made after the last master commit will appear as uncommitted in your current branch (staged)

```
4. git reset -- <filePath>
```

unstage a particular file

```
5. git commit -m "Your Commit comment"
```

Commit all the changes as one commit

```
5. git push -f origin
```

Force push to origin (your branch)

**Note**: This will converge all your Commits as one commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can stash them, follow below sequence of operations:

> git add
>
> git commit -m
>
> git stash -m ""
>
> git push

Now, to reply your local MySQL file changes

> git stash pop

Comment: The commit I would stash is 3 commits back. How can I specifically target that commit?

Comment: You don't stash your commit. It's non-committed files being stashed 
And that can retrieve by
git stash pop (if you want recent stash changes)
Or else
You can use git stash list, which will list down all the stashes.
And you can specifically apply anyone as `git stash apply {2}` eg. 3rd stash will be applied.