# How to permanently not stage a file?

Tags: git

In my project I have a config file that I do not want to stage. How can I make sure it does not get staged even when I do `git add .`  ?

Comment: How about adding it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: I don't want todo that because it is just a local version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Answer (score 5):

Ignore it :

## If it's a file nobody wants in your team

Create a file named `.gitignore` at the root of your project, add the filename into it, and **commit it** (the `.gitignore` file).

## If it's a file only you don't want

Edit the file named `.git/info/exclude` and add the filename into it.

---

More information is available here : https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: I should add : do not want to remove it from source control, just want to use a local version of a file.