# How to ignore all changes to a specific file when pushing

Tags: git

I cloned a project onto my PC from a repository and got errors because a few files had asterisks in their filename which apparently can't exist on a Windows system. So now my `git status` shows that I am deleting those files since they didn't copy over to my project. I won't need to ever make any changes with these files (they're all images), so is there a way I can tell git not to push any changes (in this case specifically deletion) for these specific files?

I tried doing `git update-index --assume-unchanged` on one of them but it doesn't appear to have worked because my `git status` still shows the file as queued for deletion (picture relevant).

[image]

Comment: If my answer has helped you, don't hesitate to upvote. If it is the correct one, feel free to to accept it.

Comment: Your answer is good and correct, but torek provided a way to apply skip-worktree to all the files at once, which was extra helpful. I did upvote you though @Cedric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Set the `--skip-worktree` bit for those particular paths in the index:

```
git ls-files -dz | xargs -0 git update-index --skip-worktree
```

(I assume your Windows-bash has `xargs -0`; if not, you might have to fiddle with this a bit.)

#### Long(ish)

Your `git update-index` command produced no errors, so it's not affecting these files, which means you're looking in the wrong place.

One fundamental issue here is that `git push` does not push *files*.  Instead, it pushes *commits*.  It's true that commits *contain* files, so you might argue that this is a useless distinction—but it's a key distinction that Git makes, and it's at the heart of both the problem, and the cure.

> ... a few files had asterisks in their filename which apparently can't exist on a Windows system

That appears to be correct ([What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/1256452)).  In one sense, it doesn't affect or bother *Git*, though, because Git deals with commits, not files.  It affects *you*. :-)

Git stores commits in its repository database.  Git also stores each version of each file in this database.  Each stored item, called an *object* internally, has a special, compressed, Git-only form.  The files inside a commit are additionally frozen that way for as long as the commit exists (typically forever).<sup>1</sup>

Frozen (read-only), Git-only files are useless to you and the rest of the programs on your computer.  So Git needs a way to extract them into read/write, useful form.  It does this in two stages: first it effectively thaws the files by listing them in its *index* (which is really just a file named `.git/index`).  The index keeps track of what is—or at least should be—in the work-tree.  Then it de-compresses them and gives them useful *names*—real file names, in the real file system—and puts them in your work-tree.

It's the last step, of turning the thawed, but still Git-only, index entry into a file name like `foo*bar`, that fails because of the forbidden name.  So the thawed entry *is* in the index, but is not in the work-tree.

Git always makes *new* commits from whatever is in the index.  Even commands like `git commit -a` really just update the index, then build the commit from the index (though some use a temporary auxiliary index just for the duration of the commit, then fix up the real index).  So until you change the copy of a file that's in the *index*, anything you do to the work-tree—including removing a file, or what Git thinks is removing since the file never got created—is just a change that is, in `git status`'s terms, *not staged for commit*.

What we'd like, though, is to avoid having `git status` complain, and avoid having `git add` *remove* the index copy of the file.  That is, if there was a file `foo*bar`, and it did not get into our work-tree, that's sort-of-OK, as long as we don't want to *do anything* with that file.  We can leave the file in the index, missing from the work-tree, and have each new `git commit` we make re-freeze the index copy.  It's just *annoying* that we have to tiptoe around the fact that there's no `foo*bar` in the work-tree.

Both of the index flags, `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree`, let us work around that fact.  The `--skip-worktree` is the flag that's *meant* for this purpose: the Git guys added it for "sparse checkout", and this is a special case of a sparse checkout.  So we can just find the list of files that `git status` will consider deleted from the work-tree—i.e., files that are listed in the index, are missing from the actual work-tree, and don't have the special flags set in the index—and set the `--skip-worktree` flag.

`git ls-files -d` prints a list of such file names.  With `-z`, it prints them terminated by an ASCII NUL (`\0`) character instead of a newline.  The `xargs -0` command reads these NUL-terminated strings and runs `git update-index --skip-worktree` on them, so now all those index entries have the flag set.  New commits will contain the files (since the index lists them), but the work-tree won't (since it can't); meanwhile `git add` won't try to remove them, and `git status` won't complain about them.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is actually part of a general rule: Git's internal objects live in a key-value store addressed by keys that are hash IDs, and the hash ID of any object is a unique, cryptographic checksum of the object's content.  The content cannot be changed because if it *were* changed, the checksum would change, after which the old key would still retrieve the old object, with only the new key / hash-ID able to retrieve the new object.

Comment: So `git ls-files -d` prints a list of all files that are committed to deletion? I only have 5 files so even if the flags aren't set up right I could run skip-worktree on each filename manually. Very cool solution though.

Comment: Nothing is committed (for any purpose at all, deletion, change, new file, whatever) yet! Whenever you run `git commit`, whatever is in the *index* goes into the new commit. If the file is in the index but not in the work-tree, the index copy of the file goes into the new commit. We're not going to change this: the copy that's in the index, named with the asterisk, is OK, and you still want it in your own new commits. You can't *change* it, but that is also OK. You just want to make Git stop *complaining* about it, and for that purpose, the `--skip-worktree` bit is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Simply: `git update-index --skip-worktree [<file>...]`

With `skip-worktree`, even where git knows that the file has been modified (or needs to be modified by a reset --hard or the like), it will pretend it has not been, using the version from the index instead. This persists until the index is discarded. [explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525)

[See *How do Iconfigure git to ignore some files locally* : git update-index --skip-worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462290/278739)

Answer (score 0):

As it was said a few days ago about similar question, it's could be a shell issue and not a git issue.

Have you tried git bash instead of windows shell ?

Have you tried to rename these file, just after pull, using escape character for the asterisk ?

Comment: I used git bash, actually. I use it exclusively instead of powershell. I'm not sure how I could rename the file after pull because the files never actually get cloned onto my system. They are missing after the pull.

Comment: Can you try to copy by hand and re-type `git status` after that ?