# Git: How to selectively remove certain files from the local change list (not from the staged list) without removing from the index?

Tags: git

Every developers will have to modify certain files to fit his/her local environment and owing to this those files will appear as a change always. If you have a large project with many such configurations, staging files would be a nightmare.

The `git update-index --assume-unchanged [<file>...]` will assume the file unchanged forever. That wont work! I still want GIT to detect if anything has changed from the 'tagged' version

**Requirement**

As a developer, I want to be able to tag/flag few (configuration) files in a project so that it will not appear in the change list unless there is a modification from the tagged version.

How can I achieve this? How others are dealing with this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - Will the file appear in the change list if it has been changed later?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own code to do this, but you cannot do this with Git "out of the box".  The closest you can get is to do what you said you *don't* want to do:

> The `git update-index --assume-unchanged [<file>...]` will assume the file unchanged forever.

Actually, you probably should use `--skip-worktree` here.  (See [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/1256452).)  Use `--no-assume-unchanged` or `--no-skip-worktree` to *clear* the bit you just set.  Make a list of files on which you have set the assume-unchanged or skip-worktree bits, and you can clear and then re-set these bits whenever you like; that's the closest you get from Git as it is today.

#### Long: why Git is so stubborn

In particular, let's look at the summary subject line:

> How [can I] selectively remove certain files from the local change list (not from the staged list) without removing from the index?

That's like asking how you can convince the Pope to switch from Islam to Buddhism.  It starts from a wrong premise!

Fundamentally, there *isn't* any "local change list", nor is there is "staged list".  There are only *commits*, the *index*, and the *work-tree*.

Each such entity contains some set of files:

- The files in any given commit are frozen, and compressed into a special Git-only format to save space.  You can never change *any* file saved inside a commit: all you can do is make a *new* commit that's very much like the old one, but with some different frozen files, and switch from your current commit (that had frozen version 17 of file A) to the new commit (that now has frozen version 18 of file A), for instance.

  (And of course you can't add a file to a frozen commit, or remove one from it. Again, you can only make a *new* commit that's mostly, but not exactly, like the previous one.)
- The files in your work-tree are unfrozen, and in ordinary format.  You, and all your computer programs, can work with these (hence the name "work-tree" or "working tree").  You can read them, write them, destroy them, do whatever you like.
- The *index*—also called, variously, the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, depending on who or what is doing the calling—lives these two positions.  Files in the index are in the special Git-only format, but they are *not* frozen.  You can replace them wholesale any time you like.

Let's add as a side note here that `HEAD` *always* represents your current commit.  (This is true even in a new, empty repository that has *no* commits: `HEAD` still represents the current commit, which doesn't exist.  This is what makes several Git commands act a little [squirrelly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squirrelly) at this point.)

Initially, the copies in the index *match* the copies in the current (and frozen) commit—and if you switch from *that* commit to some *other* commit, the copies in the index *still* match the frozen commit.  Updating from commit `a123456...` to `fedcba9...` makes Git switch out your index from "copy of `a123456`" to "copy of `fedcba9`".  In general—there are a few specific exceptions with plumbing commands—when Git *does* switch out the index copies, Git *also* switches out the *work-tree* copies.

What `git add` does is *replace* the index copy of some file with one you take from the work-tree.  So the normal process, in Git, is to `git checkout` some commit, so that `HEAD` has the frozen copies, the index has them thawed out (but the same as `HEAD`), and your work-tree has them expanded into useful form (and the same as in the index).  Then you *change* one in the work-tree and run `git add` to *copy* it *from* the work-tree back into the index.

Now the index copy *doesn't* match the `HEAD` copy, but *does* match the work-tree copy.  So it's pretty common, in Git, to have the index copy of *every* file match *one* other active copy: either the `HEAD` copy, or the work-tree copy.  But it is, of course, possible to have the index copy match *neither*, because we can modify a work-tree file, copy it into the index, then modify it *again*.  Now *all three* copies will differ.

At any time, we can run `git commit`.  This flash-freezes the *index* copies—which are already in the Git-only format, so they are all already ready—and deposits the frozen copies into the repository as the files for our new commit.  The new commit then *becomes* the current (`HEAD`) commit, and now the commit and the index match.<sup>1</sup>

(It's also possible, of course, to have files in one or more places that *aren't* in the others.  If we create an all-new work-tree file, it's not in the index now.  Using `git add` will copy it *into* the index, in the special Git-only compressed form, but not frozen.  Or, if a file is already in the index and work-tree, we can use `git rm` to remove it from both.  Of course, none of these can ever affect any frozen copy in any existing commit.)

We can, at any time, ask Git to compare the *current commit*—more precisely, all of `HEAD`'s frozen files—to the index:

```
git diff --cached
```

If we only want the *names* of "M"odified, newly-"A"dded, or "D"eleted" files, maybe including the letter-code for this state, we tell `git diff` to print only the names, or the names and letter-code, for each file:

```
git diff --cached --name-only
git diff --cached --name-status
```

In all cases Git finds the answer by *comparing* the frozen `HEAD` to the slushy index.

Likewise, we can ask Git to compare the index to the work-tree:

```
git diff
git diff --name-only
git diff --name-status
```

This does the same as before, except instead of comparing frozen `HEAD` to slushy index, it compares slushy index to liquid work-tree.

What `git status` does, to tell you about files, is to run *both of these two `git diff` operations*.  These *produce* those lists you mentioned above, but only for the duration of `git status` running: once `git status` has printed the lists and quit, those lists no longer exist.

What `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree` do is *set a particular flag bit* on some internal flags kept with each file-entry stored in the index.  These flags tell Git: *Don't bother comparing the index and work-tree copies, just assume they are the same.*  So at this point, `git status` won't *say* anything about the file.  Moreover, `git add` will assume that the index copy is good, and not update it either—updating the index copy requires re-compressing the work-tree copy, after all, which takes a noticeable amount of time.  (That's a significant part of *why* Git keeps the slushy, not-quite-frozen copy ready to go in the index.  Having the file ready to go, in the *next* commit you will make, makes `git commit` amazingly faster than older version control systems.)

Note that, since there *is* a separate copy in the index, *new* commits you make will have the file frozen into them.  They just have the *index* copy—same as the old `HEAD` copy—in them.  But if you use `git checkout` to switch from *this* commit to some *other* commit, and that other commit has a *different* copy of the frozen file, your index copy will be updated to match the *other* commit's copy.  This is where [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/1256452) comes in again.