# fail to clean file using git command

Tags: xcode, git

After merging, I checked with `git status` and cleaned with `git clean -rf`, but I was still left with the following untracked file:

`<projectName>.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/<username>.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/`

I then checked to see if it would be cleaned with `git clean -n`, and there was nothing shown, as expected (since it was not cleaned in the previous command).

Also, I have tried an alternative, that I `touch .gitignore` and added `xcuserdata` in the `.gitignore` file. Afterwards when I checked for `git status`, the untracked file becomes `.gitignore`, effectively substituting the previous untracked file, which still did not really solve my problem.

What should be the way so that I can clean up my working tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the directory is generated by `xcode` when `xcode` is running. Close `xcode` and try `git clean -df` in the console. If it can be removed properly, add it to `.gitignore`.

To ignore `.gitignore` itself, you can add the line `.gitignore` to the file `.gitignore`. Another solution is to add and commit `.gitignore`.

Comment: To ignore files locally use [`$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753078/7976758).