# Git should ignore a conf file, but it should not be in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

This is a relatively simple question, but for some reason, I cannot find an answer to it.

I have a conf file that needs to **not** be pushed to our git repository, but I cannot add it to the .gitignore (team leader doesn't want it there). Is there some way that I can get git to ignore it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore it locally https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#personal-git-ignore-rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Comment: yeah! thank you so much!