# How to write the git ignore using .git/info/exclude file

Tags: git

I have read that there is another way of ignoring files as mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/exclude-files-from-git-without-committing-changes-to-gitignore-986fa712e78d) using the .git/info/exclude. I kinda like it because there is one file less in the directory. and anyway there will be one device where this program will be coming from. I dont mind not havingg version control on the .gitingnore

The simplified directory looks like this:

- .git
- vendor
- index.php
- sometext.txt

I would like to ignore vendor and the text file. How would i ignore them the command line way and the manual text edit on the .git/info/exclude. Also vendor has already been committed(and pushed) i would like for it not to be included in future pushes.

Comment: you should look for .gitignore, but what was versioned up to this point cannot be un-versioned.

Comment: @DaemonPainter that is the point, i do not want to use .gitignore. I want to approach it using the exclude file way

Comment: Bear in mind that those excludes are _local_ and any clone of the repository will not have the same set of rules. As I said, as you already pushed, you'll also have to `git rm` it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an editor to modify this file `.git/info/exclude` to :

```
# Ignore directory vendor in repo's root only
/vendor/

# Ignore text file in repo's root only
/sometext.txt
```

This will be valid only for commits made after this change.

See [Pattern Format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) for more details on the format to exclude or include files.

Comment: if i want to ingore a file inside a folder i assume that it would also look like this: `/folder/file.txt` and a folder inside a folder `/folder1/folder2/` ? Is there really no way of removing files that are pushed (exept of course making a new git project with the same files)

Comment: @DrakeJest Yes you can use those patterns. There are ways to remove files that have been pushed but not without changing history.

Comment: Alright good to hear that, Thank you very much for your answer good sir