# Ignore old untracked files in git status

Tags: git, gitignore

This is a problem caused entirely by my own laziness. In some projects I tend to accumulate a bunch of temporary files that I don't want to delete yet, but don't want to commit either. And because they are just my local temp files, I don't want to `.gitignore` them either.

Is there a way to make `git status` only show untracked files if they have been modified in last X days?

Comment: You can ignore files without adding them to `.gitignore`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753078/7976758

Comment: @phd Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script I use now instead of `git status`:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_THRESHOLD="+30" # More than 30 days old
OLD_UNTRACKED=$(git status --porcelain=2 | \
                grep '^[?] ' | cut -d' ' -f 2- | \
                xargs -I X find X -maxdepth 0 -mtime $OLD_THRESHOLD )

git -c color.status=always status | grep -vF "$OLD_UNTRACKED"
```

It takes a list of the untracked files, and filters out any that have `mtime` older than 30 days.

Note that the untracked files will still cause you (me?) trouble in e.g. `git add folder`. It is still better to organize directories so that temporary files are in an gitignored folder.