# What is the minimal setup.py needed to develop poetry packages?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-poetry

I am developing a python package managed by poetry. The package has some complex requirements that are very difficult to install successfully on my system. I want the ability to install this in editable mode, with the ability to ignore dependencies (something which the developer of poetry [frowns](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/697#issuecomment-470431668) [on](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/34#issuecomment-378370551)). Unfortunately, I do not have the option of converting this package to a more mature packaging system.

Apparently the simple solution is to create a `setup.py` for the project and `pip install -e` that. Since unfortunately poetry has spread like a cancer to many projects now, I will have to employ such a workaround frequently. As such, I want to minimize the tedium by not copying over fields like `description` which are irrelevant to the developing the package.

What is the minimal `setup.py` file that I can use as a template for such poetry projects? I assume it must at least include the package name, version and location. Is there anything else?

I am also planning to not put any requirements in the `setup.py` file, since the whole point is to bypass the requirements defined by poetry and `pyproject.toml`. I am fine with manually resolving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'` errors by typing `pip install foo`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears sufficient to create the following file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name="<PACKAGE_NAME>",
    version="<PACKAGE_VERSION>"
)
```

And also comment out the entire `[build-system]` block in the `pyproject.toml` file (see also [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1753070/15629542) so you don't accidentally commit to that).

I think the package name and version can be automatically pulled from the toml file as well, but not sure right now how to do it.