# Poetry won't install dependency in a tarball/zip file

Tags: python, gitlab, setuptools, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

*Short version:*

How can I `poetry install` a package where one of the dependencies is a local tarball/zip file? It doesn't seem to work, yet it is shown in the `poetry` [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification)?

I can `poetry install` the package when the dependency is pulled from gitlab, but the install fails when I manually download the dependency from gitlab as a tarball and try to `poetry install` with the dependency in the tarball.

*Long version:*

I am trying to use `poetry` to install two packages that I have developed:

- a base package called `my_package`
- an extension called `extension_of_my_package`.

Both packages are in private repos in gitlab, and both have a `pyproject.toml` containing their dependency list. I can successfully `poetry install` the extended package (`extension_of_my_package`) when the base package `my_package` is downloaded from gitlab. *i.e.* the `pyproject.toml` file in `extension_of_my_package` has a `tool.poetry.source` section that gives the location of the `my_package` private repo on gitlab.

However, external users cannot access my private repo, so I need to ensure the
packages can be installed from tarballs (that I download from gitlab and give to the client).

To install `extension_of_my_package` I do this:

```
tar xzf extension_of_my_package.tgz
cd extension_of_my_package/python
```

and then edit the `pyproject.toml`, changing the dependency on `my_package` to point to
the local tarball:

```
my_package = { path = "/path/to/my_package.tgz"}
```

and then run `poetry install`. This fails with the error message:

```
> poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (9.3s)

  TypeError

  expected string or bytes-like object

  at /home/user/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/poetry/core/utils/helpers.py:27 in canonicalize_name
       23│ _canonicalize_regex = re.compile(r"[-_]+")
       24│ 
       25│ 
       26│ def canonicalize_name(name):  # type: (str) -> str
    →  27│     return _canonicalize_regex.sub("-", name).lower()
       28│ 
       29│ 
       30│ def module_name(name):  # type: (str) -> str
       31│     return canonicalize_name(name).replace(".", "_").replace("-", "_")
```

According to the `poetry` [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification) it is possible to install from a local file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# directory
my-package = { path = "../my-package/", develop = false }

# file
my-package = { path = "../my-package/dist/my-package-0.1.0.tar.gz" }
```

I also tried using `my-package = { file = ...` instead of `my-package = { path = ...`, but it didn't work either.

I tried adding a minimal `setup.py` file to `my_package` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959695/what-is-the-minimal-setup-py-needed-to-develop-poetry-packages)), but that didn't help.

I tried converting `my_package` (in tarball format) to a `wheel`. I can successfully `poetry install` when `my package` is in `wheel` format, but `my_packages`'s dependencies are not installed. I can't see how to include the dependency info in the wheel. When I created the wheel I tried specifying the
dependency info in two ways:

1. in `setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name = my_package
version = 0.1.0
description = My Package
license = Proprietary

[options]
packages = find:
install_requires =
   matplotlib >=3.2.0
```

and

2. in `setup.py`"

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name=`my_package`,
   version="0.1.0,
   packages=['.my_package'],
   install_requires=['matplotlib >= 3.2.0',]
)
```

To rule out any problem with my own package, I created a minimal test and tried to `poetry install` a publicly available package ([tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)) from its zip file (downloaded from github). It also fails. The `pyproject.toml` for this minimal test is:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "tester"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "test package"
authors = [ "me" ]
packages = [
    { include = "tester" }
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.7,<3.9"
tqdm = {file = "/home/user/tqdm-master.zip"}
```

and the error message is:

```
> poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (13.0s)

  RuntimeError

  Unable to determine package info from path: /home/user/tqdm-master.zip

  at /home/user/.poetry/lib/poetry/puzzle/provider.py:251 in get_package_from_file
      247│             package = PackageInfo.from_path(path=file_path).to_package(
      248│                 root_dir=file_path
      249│             )
      250│         except PackageInfoError:
    → 251│             raise RuntimeError(
      252│                 "Unable to determine package info from path: {}".format(file_path)
      253│             )
      254│ 
      255│         return package
```

I am using `poetry` version 1.1.13.

I am open to any alternative approaches, so long as all the dependencies are checked.

Comment: How about keeping the package in gitlab and using https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/ to install