# VSCode: ignore files without using .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I would like to ignore specific changes/files locally for git without using the `.gitignore` file. Is there a config or extension for this?

All I can find so far is to ignore these files in the `.gitignore`, however that again causes a local change for the `.gitignore` file that I then might accidentally commit.

I would find this useful to either temporarily exclude changes that might still be work in progress or specific to my system.

Comment: Or alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged xxxx  // xxxx is your specific file name(includes path)

git update-index --no-assume-unchanged xxxx  // Undo above operation
```

The official docs is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).