# Does RubyMine has a quick diff feature like Netbeans has?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubymine

I am wondering if I can turn on a quick diff feature in RubyMine. By default, in Netbeans, you see a green, blue or red bar on the left of the normal editor that shows what has been added/modified/deleted relative to the previous revision (Git or SVN).

[You can also turn this option in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220111/subclipse-marking-code-changes-like-in-netbeans).

Does it is exist in RubyMine?

---

To illustrate, On this image, you can see added code (green) and modified code (green) as a quick diff :

[image: quick diff netbeans]

Comment: [This page](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_version_control.html) details some of the options they have...

Comment: @FloydPink Looks like it exists, i'll try to see how to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [it does](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_version_control.html) and it is enabled by default if you start a project created by a VCS working copy (example a git clone or an SVN checkout).

If VCS is not enabled, you can enable it in the project settings.

Here's a preview of the inline diff.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as you have version control enabled, RubyMine will display such diffs. There is no need to turn this on; the diffs are always shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened a project cloned with git in rubymine; and if rubymine does not show the quick diff, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18255516/311744. This will tell rubymine to use the current .git.