# How to resolve git pull conflicts in xcode ui

Tags: xcode, git, pull, git-pull

I am using the Xcode repository GUI with the latest version of Xcode instead of the command line. I did an initial pull of the rep without a problem. I made some changes to the local files. At the same time, my other developer made some changes. I committed my changes to the local rep but needed his changes to  do a proper build. We only have 1 branch.

I tried to pull and the Xcode UI reports 6 conflicts (which is what I would expect as I need the 6 files to do the proper build).

My question is how to resolve the conflicts? I read online I should be able to use the left and right button at the bottom of screen to let me pick which file version. I went through all of the 6 files and used the proper buttons to choose which changes I wanted.

However the Pull button in the lower right hand corner is disabled and greyed out.

Comment: Hello everyone,

After wasting a couple of hours, the short answer is either to use the command line or use Tower Git Client. Tower is pretty awesome!!

Answer (score 11):

**Above the file listing of the commit screen are three icons, a directory view, a documents view and the last one which looks like some horizontal lines.  When I had a similar issue, I found that clicking on these revealed other files I had not yet resolved.**

I resolved those I could although noted that some of these files included some .DS-Store 's which are hidden Apple (Desktop Services Store) files which have been noted elsewhere of causing git issues.

I placed the .DS_Store into .gitignore using the instructions at [How can I Remove .DS_Store files from a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository)

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Awesome!! that BOLD lines was perfect hint!! problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just had more conflicts further down that I didn't see. Strangely, since using Xcode 6 this is the first time I've actually had to deal with conflicts -- and I made them! (on a different machine)

At any rate, just scrolling down a bit more revealed that there were more conflicts in the file and once I chose "right" or "left" (or "right then left"/"left then right"), the "Pull" button enabled and I was able to complete my pull...

Whew! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a file that had been deleted in the branch but was still present in Master. Once I unchecked that file, I was able to Pull.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen in Xcode 9.4.1, and what I needed to do, after having resolved all the conflicts, was the following:

- Switch to Source Control view in the left pane above the tree view (the box with a cross symbol in it)
- Toggle the checkbox next to the top-level project entry from off to on. This would enable the Pull button, but just for a second, not long enough to click it.
- Toggle the checkbox back to off, and back to on again. Now the Pull button remains enabled.
- Click *Pull*.

This feels very much like a bug; I haven't verified yet if the issue persists, and the solution still works, in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 0):

Just do "git pull" from the command line, then rebuild to find the conflict markers and fix them manually.