# Ignoring .DS_Store in a gitignore file using Tower

Tags: gitignore, git-tower

I have a new repo and before I perform the first commit I'd like to ignore .DS_Store files.

I've tried adding the following to the .gitignore file via Tower:

```
.DS_Store
*.DS_Store
*/.DS_Store
```

But only the .DS_Store file at the root is ignored, all others are included ready for commit.

Is there a trick to getting these files to be ignored?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you didn't add to the index those DS_Store first.

If you did, check out "[How Can I Remove .DS_Store Files From A Git Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107701/6309)", and then check if your `.gitignore` works.
Use `git rm --cached` if you want just to remove then from the index while keeping them in the working tree.

Note: only `.DS_Store` should be enough in your case.

See [`Objective-C.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore) from the [GitHub Collection of Useful `.gitignore` Templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: Thanks for that, I hadn't added them to the repo because I hadn't done the first commit. IN the end I just gave up and committed them.

Answer (score 19):

**/.DS_Store

try it out :) Hope it help