# .gitignore all the .DS_Store files in every folder and subfolder

Tags: git, macos, gitignore

I've added .DS_Store to the .gitignore file, but it seems that it is only ignoring .DS_Store in the root directory, not in every folder and subfolder.

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Remove .DS\_Store Files From A Git Repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: How exactly did you add it to .gitignore? It should work in all directories (does for me).

Comment: Its working for me as well. I also tried when its at the end of the file, if you have to have a (platform specific) newline but that didn't change that .DS_Store directories within any part of the hierarchy was still ignored.

Comment: The question as I understand it was: How to easily ignore all occurrences of .DS_Store in all subdirectories without manually doing this in every subdirectory. I had the same problem. The below answer shows how to solve it (the last 2 paragraphs).

Answer (score 1033):

I think the problem you're having is that in some earlier commit, you've accidentally added `.DS_Store` files to the repository.  Of course, once a file is tracked in your repository, it will continue to be tracked even if it matches an entry in an applicable .gitignore file.

You have to manually remove the `.DS_Store` files that were added to your repository.  You can use

```
git rm --cached .DS_Store
```

Once removed, git should ignore it.  You should only need the following line in your root `.gitignore` file: `.DS_Store`.  Don't forget the period!

```
git rm --cached .DS_Store
```

removes only `.DS_Store` from the current directory. You can use

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

to remove all `.DS_Stores` from the repository.

**Felt tip:** Since you probably never want to include `.DS_Store` files, make a global rule.  First, make a global `.gitignore` file somewhere, e.g.

```
echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore_global
```

Now tell git to use it for all repositories:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

[This page](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) helped me answer your question.

Comment: ´´git rm --cached .DS_Store´´ removes only one .DS_Store from the current directory. Use ´´find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch´´ to remove all .DS_Stores from the repo

Comment: A list of other common files to ignore might be handy

Comment: Bad idea to use global rule IMO: Trying to maintain global configs across multiple users/machines never works- you want the rules governing your repo in the repo itself. [Agree with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository#comment1897703_107921)

Comment: I don't agree with you.  (Even though I upvoted your comment since I think it's insightful.)  If we do global, then every mac user needs to do that, but only once.  If we do repository wide, then we need to do that for every repository.  I don't know about you, but I make new repos all the time.  By doing it globally, one solves the problem once and for all.

Comment: Awesome answer! It's not recommend for Global ignore because hard to team collaboration.

Comment: Use `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch -f`if you have already staged some .DS_Store files.

Comment: it works, only a few tag is missing as of today to make it work. I used it for the ".idea" folders. The only addition here is the -r -f tag I needed to add. I hope it helps:

# find . -name .idea -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -r -f --ignore-unmatch

Comment: I had staged the files but not committed them.  Unstaging the files (`git reset -- <path/to/file>`) did not work (they were shown as new).  I had to commit them then do the `git rm` to remove them.

Comment: I ran the git remove command but the PR is unchanged. It seems to have deleted locally only. when I try to commit the changes it says there's none to commit. I also tried pushing with force but that obv didn't work since there are no commits

Comment: Here's how you get the path to the global Git ignore file: `git config --get core.excludesfile`. For me it is different than the path in this answe.

Answer (score 476):

**Add`**/.DS_Store` into `.gitignore` for the sub directory**

---

If `.DS_Store` already committed:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

---

To ignore them in all repository: (sometimes it named `._.DS_Store`)

```
echo ".DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Comment: still uploaded into my repo ?

Comment: @FreddySidauruk use `git rm --cached your_file` first

Comment: @FreddySidauruk 
Should be `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch`, from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393498/gitignore-all-the-ds-store-files-in-every-folder-and-subfolder/26454988#comment46723678_19299889

Comment: It seems adding `-f` is needed if you have open files in the relavent folders: `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch`

Comment: And the same in one line: `printf "%b\n" ".DS_Store\n._.DS_Store\n**/.DS_Store\n**/._.DS_Store\n" >> ~/.gitignore_global && git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

Answer (score 271):

If .DS_Store was never added to your git repository, simply add it to your .gitignore file.

If you don't have one, create a file called

```
.gitignore
```

In the root directory of your app and simply write

```
**/.DS_Store
```

In it. This will never allow the .DS_Store file to sneak in your git.

But, if it's already there, write in your terminal:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
```

then commit and push the changes to remove the .DS_Store from your remote repo:

```
git commit -m "Remove .DS_Store from everywhere"

git push origin master
```

And now add .DS_Store to your .gitignore file, and then again commit and push with the 2 last pieces of code (git commit..., git push...)

Comment: Why double asterisk? What does that mean?

Comment: @MilanG it's a keyword that basically means 'search in this directory and all subdirectories'.

Comment: Not sure that is a perfect explanation of what the double asterisk stands for. It is a wildcard. Could `*` or `**` depending on what you want to achieve. It is a way of telling the shell how to navigate directories.  This stackoverflow answer explains it fully https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199633/4092170

Comment: ** will never match hidden (./) directories : https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/

Comment: worked like a charm. you have to do it step by step as indicated here, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Also mind if you try to adapt this example for non-`.DS_store`-files: If you want to exclude all files with this suffix you need to set the wildcard (asterisk `*`) also for the file name: `**\*.csv`

Comment: This is cool, I also use `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete` to delete all created .DS_store recursively

Answer (score 111):

Your **.gitignore** file should look like this:

```
# Ignore Mac DS_Store files
.DS_Store
```

As long as you don't include a slash, it is matched against the file name in all directories. (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository#comment15790551_107921))

Comment: it's still uplaoded into repo

Comment: @FreddySidauruk then you have to run `git rm --cached path/to/file/here`

Answer (score 101):

**Simply place this on a new line in `.gitignore`**

```
**/.DS_Store
```

From [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> - A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

Comment: As noted in the documentation you quote, `**/.DS_Store` is just a more complicated way of writing `.DS_Store`. You only need the double star when you want to gitignore a specific path pattern, regardless of where it occurs. For example `**/foo/.DS_Store` would hide `.DS_Store` files only if found in a `foo` subdirectory (regardless of where `foo` is).

Comment: @orlp has it always been like that? I would have sworn I'd added .DS_Store to .gitignore a million times, only to have .DS_Store appear in subdirectories. After testing your information it appears you're absolutely right. It changes my thinking on this SO question. But also more generally: there's a (high) risk of accidentally ignoring files in subdirectories that happen to be the same name as another that is intentionally ignored elsewhere. Seems like a bad (albeit convenient) for git to behave like that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 33):

Step 1, delete all the `*.DS_store` files. One can run

```
git rm -f *.DS_Store
```

but be aware that `rm -f` can be a bit dangerous if you have a typo! 
Step two: add

```
*.DS_Store
.DS_Store
```

to .gitignore. This worked for me!

Answer (score 18):

Add `*.DS_Store` to your .gitignore file. That works for me perfectly

Answer (score 14):

You can also add the `--cached` flag to auco's answer to maintain local .DS_store files, as Edward Newell mentioned in his original answer. The modified command looks like this: `find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch` ..cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Step :1)Remove the existing files using this command

find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch

Step : 2)Add .DS_Store in your .gitignore file

Step :3) Commit your changes in .gitignore
    git add .gitignore
    git commit -m "removed .DS_Store"

Answer (score 7):

1. `$ git rm ./*.DS_Store` - remove all .DS_Store from git
2. `$ echo \.DS_Store >> .gitignore` - ignore .DS_Store in future

commit & push

Answer (score 6):

You should add following lines while creating a project. It will always ignore `.DS_Store` to be pushed to the repository.

`*.DS_Store` this will ignore .DS_Store while code commit.
`git rm --cached .DS_Store` this is to remove .DS_Store files from your repository, in case you need it, you can uncomment it.

```
## ignore .DS_Store file.
# git rm --cached .DS_Store
*.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to do this globally so you never have to think about `.DS_Store` again:

1. Find the path to the global Git ignore file:
   `git config --get core.excludesfile`
2. Append `.DS_Store` to the global Git ignore file
3. Re-run your Git CLI command / IDE action

From this point on, Git will act as if you've placed the patterns in the global Git ignore file into your local ignore file every time.