# Switching from pc to mac - moving project folders. What to do with .git?

Tags: git, macos-sierra

next week I get my new Mac. Now I have a pc, so that I have to move my project folders from the pc to the Mac.

A project folder looks something link this:

Top-Folder: project-domain.com
Sub-Folders: docs, pdfs, images, theme

In the folder "theme" there's a WordPress theme, which is managed with git. So there are the theme files and the .git folder.

There are currently 186 project folders with similar structure. In some of them are more than one git project (e.g. plugins).

Now what's the best workflow for moving those folders and files to the mac? Moving everything including the .git folders? Or is there a way to leave folders with .git in them automatically out? Then I could fetch the repositories from the server...

What would you do? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have any issues moving the whole thing, `.git` files included.

I recently did the same migration and it worked fine. Only thing you should consider is adding `.gitignores` for `.DS_Store` files created in macOS.

Check this out: [.gitignore all the .DS_Store files in every folder and subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393498/gitignore-all-the-ds-store-files-in-every-folder-and-subfolder)

Good luck with the switch!