# I have tons of "Untracked Files" in git in Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, version-control

I am using git with Xcode but when i commit files using Xcode (not command line) after committing and pushing to remote, when i use `git status` this is the result.

What are `Untracked Files`. What should i do with them?
And what about `Changes not staged for commit` part? What are they?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These untracked files are files that have been added to your directory structure (e.g. it would appear that you did a `pod install`), but you have neither added them to source control nor told git to ignore them. (I would tell git to ignore them, personally.)

But you have to decide whether you want to add the `Pods` directory to your repo or whether you'd like to ignore them. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control. (I personally don't put `Pods` into source control, just the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock`. There are many opinions on that topic, though.)

Re the `.DS_Store`, we often have a `~/.gitignore_global` that tells it to ignore those, too. Once you tell it to ignore these, they will be removed from the “untracked” files list. See [.gitignore all the .DS_Store files in every folder and subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18393498/1271826).

Re the unstaged `.DS_Store` it looks like your repo already had that one `.DS_Store` in the repo. I would suggest removing it from the repo. See [How can I Remove .DS_Store files from a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107701/1271826).

In short, it looks like you have a project with no `.gitignore` file (or it is missing entries). It also looks like you don’t have a `~/.gitignore_global` to ignore `.DS_Store` files.

---

For an example of a `.gitignore` that you might use for Swift projects, see https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore (though, like I said, I generally would uncomment the `Pods` from that particular `.gitignore`).