# Could not exclude from source control folder from github repository

Tags: git, github

Super simple question I am sure I am missing but just can't find what:

Here is how my repository looks like:

[image]

In this `.gitignore` file there is the following content:

```
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*

.settings
target
.project
.classpath
.springBeans
.metadata
Servers
.recommenders
.classpath
/Spring4SoapProducer/target/
```

Where most important is the last line. I want the target folder of this not to be under source control.

But as you can already guess it is. I am getting this when I go for `git status` in folder directory localy.

[image]

I tried like all variations like `/Spring4SoapProducer/target/`, `Spring4SoapProducer/target/`, `./Spring4SoapProducer/target/`, `*/target`

Well none of it helped also I am commiting the `.gitignore` file before trying `get status` again .

Someone please I'm sure it is something stupid that I am missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`git rm --cached <file>`

it should would remove `<file>` from version control, while keeping it in the working repository.

Answer (score 2):

If a file is already under version control, then Git will **not** ignore the file even if it's in the `.gitignore` file.  The answer is that you need to remove the files in that directory from version control.  Then, with your ignore in place, Git will ignore all files under that directory.

My answer in another question might help you with doing this: [Removing .xcuserstate and DS_Store files from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868857/removing-xcuserstate-and-ds-store-files-from-git/21878392#21878392)