# Can I restrict uploading certain file extension in github.com?

Tags: git, file, file-upload, github, restriction

I starting a new project.

And me and my members use github to share code.

However, since we all use OSX, every folder each of us made has .DS_Store file.

Currently, we personally remove every .DS_Store file for every commit.

.DS_Store file does effect on code, but it is cause of conflict.

Is there handy way to restrict upload .DS_Store extension in github.com?

Thanks:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to the .gitignore file at the root of the project:

```
.DS_Store
```

and commit the file. Then git will ignore those files.

See [How can I Remove .DS_Store files from a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository) for how to remove the already committed .DS_Store files.