# Issue with Pushing Changes to GitHub with NetBeans

Tags: git, github, netbeans, git-commit, git-push

I am currently using NetBeans with GitHub to save my project. However, I've been having some trouble committing the changes. It keeps producing errors that I have been unable to solve, even after looking them up on the internet. I have attached a video of the errors.

[Video of the Errors](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/79435335/132960447-f1eb2bfc-9a7a-45ec-b31d-1cf4ead62192.mp4)

Edit: `git status` prints:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   pom.xml
    new file:   runPom.xml
    modified:   src/ios/Default-Info.plist
    new file:   src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Gluon-ipad-app-icon-76@2x.png
    modified:   src/ios/assets/iTunesArtwork
    modified:   src/ios/assets/iTunesArtwork@2x
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/DrawerManager.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/DrawerManager.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/MySecondApplication.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/Therabot.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/utils/BrowseUtils.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/utils/BrowseUtils.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/OctonaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/OctonaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/PrimaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/PrimaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/QuaternaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/QuaternaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/QuinaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/QuinaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/SecondaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/SecondaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/SenaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/SenaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/SeptenaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/SeptenaryView.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/Session.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/Session.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/Sessions.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/Sessions.java
    new file:   src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/Subsession.java
    renamed:    src/main/java/com/mysecondapplication/views/TertiaryView.java -> src/main/java/com/superpengoo/views/TertiaryView.java
    modified:   src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/jni-config.json
    modified:   src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json
    modified:   src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/resource-config.json
    modified:   src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/serialization-config.json
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/style.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/style.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/octonary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/octonary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/primary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/primary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/quaternary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/quaternary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/quinary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/quinary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/secondary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/secondary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/senary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/senary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/septenary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/septenary.css
    renamed:    src/main/resources/com/mysecondapplication/views/tertiary.css -> src/main/resources/com/superpengoo/views/tertiary.css

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Gluon-ipad-app-icon-76@2x.jpeg

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .DS_Store
    src/.DS_Store
    src/ios/.DS_Store
    src/ios/assets/.DS_Store
    src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/.DS_Store
    src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/.DS_Store
    src/main/.DS_Store
    src/main/java/.DS_Store
    src/main/java/com/.DS_Store
    src/main/java/com/superpengoo/.DS_Store
    src/main/resources/.DS_Store
    src/main/resources/META-INF/.DS_Store
    src/test/
    target/
```

Edit2: new `git status` output:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .DS_Store
    src/.DS_Store
    src/ios/.DS_Store
    src/ios/assets/.DS_Store
    src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/.DS_Store
    src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/.DS_Store
    src/main/.DS_Store
    src/main/java/.DS_Store
    src/main/java/com/.DS_Store
    src/main/java/com/superpengoo/.DS_Store
    src/main/resources/.DS_Store
    src/main/resources/META-INF/.DS_Store
    src/test/
    target/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
superpengooooo@Ariettas-MacBook-Pro Therabot % git add
Nothing specified, nothing added.
hint: Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addEmptyPathspec false"
superpengooooo@Ariettas-MacBook-Pro Therabot % git add .DS_Store
        src/.DS_Store
        src/ios/.DS_Store
        src/ios/assets/.DS_Store
        src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/.DS_Store
        src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/.DS_Store
        src/main/.DS_Store
        src/main/java/.DS_Store
        src/main/java/com/.DS_Store
        src/main/java/com/superpengoo/.DS_Store
        src/main/resources/.DS_Store
        src/main/resources/META-INF/.DS_Store
        src/test/
        target/
zsh: permission denied: src/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/ios/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/ios/assets/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/ios/assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/main/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/main/java/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/main/java/com/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/main/java/com/superpengoo/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/main/resources/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/main/resources/META-INF/.DS_Store
zsh: permission denied: src/test/
zsh: permission denied: target/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the video shows:

[image: Error]

Check first with a git status (in command line) if you see `pom.xml` as untracked, or locally modified: you might need to add and commit it first, before attempting your pull again.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I am seeing some files that are untracked, but `pom.xml` is not one of them. See my updated question.

Comment: @cocobeans Yes, pom.xml is modified, amongst others. Add and commit everything, then try again to pull.

Comment: Oh, I see. That worked because then I was able to choose between conflicting files. Thank you!!

Comment: actually, never mind, although it shows that everything has been updated to GitHub in NetBeans, GitHub is not showing any changes, and the command terminal still says a similar thing (see the question).

Comment: @cocobeans You should ignore DS_Store folders: https://stackoverflow.com/q/107701/6309. Then you can try again, add commit, and pull.