# How can i ignore .ds_store using gitpython?

Tags: python, gitpython

I am using GitPython.
When i commit some files from local to github, there will commit lot of .ds_store files.
There was no change global gitignore config.
How can i ignore .ds_store using gitpython, is there any idea?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository